# What to do when users do not understand/appreciate constructive feedback?

Tags: discussion, behavior

**Edit**: since the question is gone, for reasons of documentation and making this thread useful for future readers, I'm adding a photo of the thread I took with my phone from when I flagged OPs comment.
[image: photo of question, hi res]

[This question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057031/alignment-in-ios), especially [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057031/alignment-in-ios#comment57842926_35057031) is really disappointing.

**edit**: The comment from OP got deleted as a result of my flag. Paraphrasing: "I know what I'm doing here, mind your own mf business"

Obviously, this user opted to not only ignore the friendly and constructive comments but started to get offensive.

Besides this being annoying for me personally, I think that the user will carry on (because he seems to think he's doing it right) like this.

Suppose a user was to troll and continue like this, is there anything to do about it except downvoting and flagging?

Will such a supposed user see any consequences other than bad reputation?

Comment: Eh, flag and move on. If there's a pattern of abusive behaviour from the account, the mods will (eventually) catch up and deal with it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so and did. Just wondered if there is a system in place that catches such behavior in the long run other than humans;)

Comment: It is a helpdesk question.  The user doesn't give a bean about how the desk operates, he just wants an answer and move on with his project.  He got one.  Only real constructive thing you can do is recognizing the pattern and voting accordingly.  That worked too.  Ensuring that he won't be back, that doesn't work that well.

Comment: Have some comments been removed between then and now?

Comment: @Jongware yes. The OPs comment, telling me (paraphrasing here) that he's knowing what he's doing and I'm to mind my own "mf" business. Flagged that as offensive, got deleted.

Comment: [Yet another prime example of this behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067574/c-c-long-coding-problems#comment57858468_35067574).

Comment: I call them a butthole then I give them the old Good Day To You Sir and if they talk back I rebut with I SAID GOOD DAY.  It's super effective.

Comment: @Will maybe a "and a good day to you, sir/madam" would serve even better in the first place.

Comment: Nah.  Less chance to antagonize, that way.

Comment: The question is not publicly visible anymore - so we cannot really discuss the matter anymore. I tend to think that one cannot do much more really in such situations but who knows.

Comment: @JanGreve Why not take a screen shot? I am unable to read the comments, since the uploaded picture is so small.

Comment: @onebree because I didn't care take one when it was not deleted yet. I only happened to text a photo to a friend. I will re-upload with higher res, though.

Comment: @Trilarion Many people here can see deleted questions (if not deleted comments) by amassing far to many imaginary unicorn internet points.

Comment: Thanks to the screenshot I can now participate: Well, this guy is rather impolite. This is a reason for flagging the comment. Such a comment should have no place here! So my advice: flaging the comment and downvoting the question (if it deserves it) and moving on.

Comment: That argument, *"If you won't answer my question, please sod off and ignore this question"*, I see it in different wordings quite often and it annoys me much. If I see it in response to decent advice (about either code, debugging or just how to write a question), I just want that question to be removed from the earth.

Comment: I love that 'mind your own business' phrase from these slefish, sociopathic, rude posters.  SO is not a business exercise for question-posters, (there is no charge or payment), and so, if they followed their own 'advice', they would not have posted their question in the first place.

Comment: Related: [The rudeness on SO is too damn high](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262791/the-rudeness-on-stack-overflow-is-too-damn-high/309018#309018)

Comment: Maybe don't comment ask smugly as you did, and you won't get a defensive response.

Comment: @JanGreve Only an Indian Users can do this that i am 100% sure.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Some users think they're doing everything right, and won't accept constructive criticism. The other day I encountered a user who asked an "unclear" question: the end goal was clear, but the question as posted was clearly a "gimme teh codez": no effort shown at all.

Unfortunately, of course some low-rep users found it necessary to dump the code for the OP in their answers, and I was once again left looking like the stubborn rule enforcer who doesn't want to help people.

Nothing you can do here but flag offensive comments, downvote and vote to close unclear or otherwise off-topic questions. You can put the user on a "shit list" (either mental or in some notepad) and ignore further questions of them.

Comment: '  left looking like the stubborn rule enforcer who doesn't want to help people' - you're not the only ones:(   This is normal, both from posters who don't immediately get their homework copypasta code and from student voting-rings who post any old rubbish and don't want interference from 'elitist snobs' :((

Comment: "some low-rep users"...I actually see this behavior in high-rep users more than low-rep ones

Comment: Hang on - his question wasn't clear, but he got an answer.
Maybe you are just a stubborn, stubborn rule enforcer :P ;)

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it ignores the poor attitude of the comments, as noted in the [answer below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315758/1394393). Just because you're right doesn't mean you said it in the proper way, and that has a *massive* influence on a person's response.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm discussing the general case, not this specific instance.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think how you phrase your advice *is* part of the general case.

Answer (score 11):

> Obviously, this user opted to not only ignore the friendly and constructive comments

Your comments weren't friendly: they were polite for sure but what's friendly about telling someone what to do, making a snide remark about their expectations and then implying they don't know what SO is?

**Even though you were bang on the money with every comment it still wasn't friendly!**

This part:

> Also, please edit you expectations alongside that process.

particularly stood out to me as unnecessarily antagonistic. It may depend on the person reading / hearing it but if someone said this to me after offering some advice I'd be a bit hacked off as it feels like a snide and rather confrontational remark. I wouldn't be very happy if someone said it to me in real life but I'm a nice person so would try to laugh it off depending on their tone / body language, a lot harder to gauge online!

If you are using canned text for these replies might I be so bold as to  suggest an adjustment?

> I suggest reading the how to ask a good question guide and trying to adjust your question to fit in with it because currently it is missing quite a few important details. Also don't get your hopes up about the code: Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service.* Once that's done you should get more and better replies.

*I still don't like this part but I know it is sort of a tag line people like to use.

So to answer your question about 'What to do...' I would have to say look at the situation as a whole, see if there is anything you could have done to prevent it happening and if there is, learn from it and do it so going forward. And report them to the SO fuzz. :-)

Comment: Your criticism is welcome; You convinced me to reword the relevant template for future use even before your suggestion.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't need my suggestion but I'd spent so long thinking about how I would have said it I couldn't not put it in. Now I'm off to post a bad question in the hopes of seeing your new reply...

Comment: I appreciated a text to just copypasta;) I ended up replacing 'please edit you expectations alongside that process.' with 'don't get your hopes up about the code,', just in case you we don't run into each other :)

Comment: This hit home for me--I often comment the way that @JanGreve did and thought nothing of it.  Thanks for reminding us that _polite_ is not the same as _friendly_.

Comment: I wouldn't even call, "please edit you expectations" polite or professional, personally. If you want it polite/professional, something more like, "StackOverflow is design primarily for sharing *knowledge* rather than code. Sometime code is demonstrated in an answer, but it is used primarily as an example to teach a concept. Asking for someone to write your code is heavily frowned upon."

Answer (score -20):

I really think this was over-reaction. Looking at the question and its answer, it appears that the question was reasonable and narrowly-focused, especially given that the answer was one line of code. In my mind "gimme teh codez" questions are ones which say something like, "Quick! How do I implement Levenshtein Distance in Java - and hurry! My exam is over in, like, 10 minutes!!!!". THAT is a downvote-and-close. One line about how to center a control? C'mon - that's a different thing altogether, and deserves (and got) an answer. Closing as "too broad" is ridiculous.

If the user got out of line with a comment then obviously the comment deserves to be deleted and the user warned. But close-and-delete for this question? IMO unnecessary and unwarranted.

Best to all.

Comment: My post here was not about the closing but about the OPs reaction to my constructive criticism. Also, as there are different approaches to layout in iOS, the question is absolutely not narrow enough to answer. The answer it got fails when a different approach is used by OP, also is not in the language requested by OP

Comment: *I really think this was over-reaction.*  You can't be serious.  I am sad(((

Comment: @user3100115 - completely serious. Cheers.

Comment: Wow, 17 downvotes? Isnt it just delightful when all the pedantic mods jump on and upvote each other incessantly, then downvote in unison? Just a great crowd of people all around.

Comment: @lux - personally, I don't take it personally - and anyways, it's 29 down and 12 up. :-) Others have a different opinion than mine - OK, I'm good with than. However, as a father of three I'm kind of honor-bound not to let peer pressure force me into changing my opinion. And as an opinionated SOB, I'm not changing my opinion. :-) Cheers.