# How does Stack Overflow handle spammers?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

As a part of my academic project I have made a small question and answer forum named [getAnswers](http://www.getanswers.in) with the help of a framework.

I have been getting spammers mostly, who are signing up to the website with a confirmed email id and posting promotional content.

The users register with domains like `g.gsasearchengineranker.website`,`spambog.ru` and more.

It would be really helpful if one can share little bit of information on the same.

Comment: See [SmokeDetector](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector) for instance. Spam posts will be quickly flagged as such as soon detected. I think the SE engine also has some features to keep spam accounts out.

Comment: @Stijn Sorry if the same is not relevant but I tried to ask the same in `Stack Overflow` and was mentioned it's off-topic and should be listed in `meta.stackoverflow`.

Comment: By the way, there's a section dedicated to preventing spam in the documentation of the software you use: http://docs.question2answer.org/addons/

Comment: @Stijn I'm aware of that, and the same is activated yet it doesn't resolve the problem I'm facing with spammers

Comment: I assume you'd rather prevent spammers from entering at all rather than cleaning up after their mess - a form of [captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) can help with that. The spam cleanup measures are very necessary on SO because users can post content without signing up first. Your site however forces you to sign in first.

Comment: @Gimby I totally agree on the measures you have pointed out, but we don't let the user post until the user verify their `Email Id`, the persons or the users verifies their email ids and after that they post `promotional content`. If I are to stop these persons from registering in that case a major question might arise which is `based on what parameters` we differentiate a user to be a `real user` and a `spammer`

Comment: @Gimby - users do have to sign up in order to post on SO. This was changed a few years ago. Most of the other sites are indeed open and do not required registration.

Comment: @Will Hahaha yeah exactly but it would be better if there's an automated system, for the time being we are planning to track the `domain` of the blocked users. So that if someone else from the same domain tries to register we won't even allow them, It's exactly what you have stated above. As these domain seems to be a company or something working on seo ranking, I guess

Comment: Oh, there is an automated system.  Its name is [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).  Fear it.

Comment: Don't fear Community.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The first line of defence is our users - people see spam and flag it. These flags go into a high-priority moderator queue, which is important for sites with low traffic (as they might not accumulate 6 flags very quickly - see next paragraph).

The system will automatically delete a post with 6 spam flags.

If a moderator flags a post as spam it will be deleted immediately.

These flags (and the deletion) feed into a system (called SpamRam) that will automatically block source IP addresses and ranges (I will not go into details about exactly how that works and what the thresholds are, for obvious reasons).

The system gets a few hundred such flags every day and blocks hundreds (on some days thousands/tens of thousands) of spam posts a day.

---

Other than that, the community has created [a bot](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector) ([GitHub repo](//github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector)) that will report on spam and will help users converge on it and remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe I have got the information how stack overflow handles this issue.

Comment: Might be worth adding that any posts flagged as spam immediately enter the mod queue as high priority which for low-traffic tags/posts not detected by the bot or otherwise don't accumulate the necessary six community votes, they will still be handled appropriately.

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for the valuable information. It has given me the basic idea about the flow it operates

Comment: @silverFox Also - if a post is successfully deleted as spam - the contents of the post are hidden with place holder text for 10k+ users (the reputation required to see deleted posts) although they can still click through to see the original content)... For long spam answers that can reduce the screen space when scrolling through a question. It's less a "how is it handled" but it's a nice feature.

Comment: @JonClements Wow!! That's really interesting, I never thought about the long answers. That's really helpful. Thank you a lot sir

Answer (score 28):

Oded's answer gives the details of how the built-in system handles spam; I'm here to give a little bit more detail about SmokeDetector, the community-built spam-detection bot, in the hopes that there might be some ideas in it you can make use of.

Stack Exchange has a [page](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) that shows all questions as they update in real time. Behind the scenes, that's powered by a websocket that feeds all question updates. SmokeDetector hooks into this websocket to get the same feed of updating questions.

Every time a post is received from this websocket, SmokeDetector fetches the content of that post from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), then runs the post (including its title and its author's username) through a [series of checks](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/findspam.py#L346-L524) to detect whether or not it's likely to be spam.

Those checks are a mixture of regexes and simple methods, and are based on characteristics of spam we've seen previously. Every suspected spam post is sent to our web dashboard, [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/), so that we have a permanent record of it that we can use in the future to check up on the system's accuracy and to improve the existing checks.

We've also experimented with machine learning and natural language processing techniques to try to detect spam, but so far neither of those methods has come up with results as accurate as a team of humans building regexes.

Currently, the Charcoal team (the people behind SmokeDetector) are working with Stack Exchange to explore options for integrating the bot with the Stack Exchange system itself to improve spam detection and prevention. That's come about as a necessity of the fact that the systems are separate - if you could build something like SmokeDetector *into* your Q&A site, I get the feeling it would be a much better solution from the off.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer. That's really amazing to know that all these processes are going on as we speak and especially about the `SmokeDetector`, I'm not sure if we can build a solution like that but we will try to do our best to come up with something which helps us out.

Comment: @silverFox Don't go to build it, Become famous like SO and people like Art will build it for you

Comment: @BhargavRao  Hahaha well SO is in a complete different level  will take us decades to reach their but we created it just to know how a Q&A site works 