# Automating duplicate question detection

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I was simply wondering if there was anything in place to automatically detect duplicate questions?

Perhaps some users are crawling the site and are using some techniques (string matching or machine learning for instance) to detect duplicates, but is there an official (read run by stackoverflow)

Would it be interesting to have this to help moderate the site?

Comment: As soon as you have solid way to detect "no research is done" condition picking first SO hit for title of the question on Google/Bing is trivial part.

Comment: I'm not sure how feasible it is to do this without human intervention; sometimes a few words can make all the difference, and programming questions are by nature permutations of a limited corpus of terminology. But the function that suggests duplicates while you're typing a question could definitely be improved.

Comment: I think a “likelyhood of being a dup” score would be a better way to proceed. A high score would give people pause and allow them to address it, whereas a “this is a duplicate” message would be ignored after encountering a few false positives.

Comment: Google (the search leader, right?) is amazing, but way way worse than human still. While machine learning is conquering humanity, it's still not able to do broad stuff. You probably should ask such question in 2027.

Comment: You can probably never automate this process, since the procedure of spotting a duplicate almost always requires domain knowledge.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Project reduplication of deduplication has begun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286329)

Comment: Given how [broken the Stack Overflow search engine is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357462/1889329), it is unlikely for an automated duplicate checker based on it to make this site any more efficient. It would just get flooded with false positives and suffer from lots of false negatives.

Comment: We have system that detects duplicate from comments past by user and we find a lot of [Duplicate Posts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117458/duplicate-posts), the problem is not finding questions to close vote, the problem is finding people who are willing to review and vote.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence suggests that 99% of the time when a post contains the phrase "this is not a duplicate of [question X]" it's a duplicate of question X.

Comment: Indeed, I did try to search the list of questions to see if this was asked beforehand. Perhaps another question then. Is there a way to "merge" duplicate questions that have been both commented on?

Answer (score 15):

> [I asked because I am currently looking for a m[a]ster's thesis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359084/automating-duplicate-question-detection?cb=1#comment530328_359085)

Well, good luck. No two people describe a problem the same way, and a *lot* of questions actually are XY problems due to a lack of experience, lack of research or both. So the phrasing of the question isn't going to find the answer the asker needs.

The kind of questions you *are* going to match up with canonical duplicates by text matching are *"How can I replace a string"* or *"How to write this RegEx"* kind of questions, which will be downvoted into oblivion and deleted before you can find a duplicate, unless a 100K+ user answers them before that point.

But keep us posted, I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: _"downvoted into oblivion and deleted"_ ... you know... hopefully.

Comment: Another common type of detecting it would be to just look at errors in the text. Most MATLAB dupes are "Error using <operator> Matrix dimensions must agree". I assume similar things in other tags

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing official that detects duplicates.  Well, you *could* count the message you get when looking at the question dupe dialog...but I'd hardly count that as useful.

Certain users use techniques to keep track of dupes, such as favoriting known canonical questions and referring back to that list, or simply Googling a key phrase or two.

It'd be infinitely useful to have this, and as far as I know, Stack Overflow is acutely aware of this and hopes to have it addressed Soon™.

Comment: I asked because I am currently looking for a msster's thesis, and doing this type of work would definitely be useful. Thanks a lot for your answer. If I were to develop such a system, how could it be implemented in Stackoverflow? Is there a developer option?

Comment: Your only *real* option here would be to download the [SEDE data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and mine through it.  There are APIs but you're not going to get the level of throughput (or flexibility) needed to reliably detect anything.  **Good luck.**

Comment: There are some bot's/algorithms like [SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336288/how-does-stack-overflow-handle-spammers/336331#336331)(for spam) and a [automatic comment flagging bot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343065/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-non-answers-and-post-comments-on-them-automatica). Having a reliable tool for duplicate detection would be a great step forward.

Comment: @ValentinCalomme http://papers.www2017.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/proceedings/p1221.pdf, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11390-015-1576-4, http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7832919

Comment: @ValentinCalomme did you read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286329/project-reduplication-of-deduplication-has-begun?

Comment: @BDL we actual have a [tool](https://stackapps.com/questions/6910/) that even can ping you live in chat, but the problem is that considering the volume it's very hard to find people willing to invest time to review and close'em, some moderation orientated chat rooms use it on specific tags eg [GMTs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75819/gmts)

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow already tries to suggest duplicates. When you're marking a question as a duplicate, Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange sites) comes with a list of *Similar questions frequently linked or suggested as originals*

As you can see (you can attempt marking questions as a duplicate), that list is far from perfect, and even further from fully automating flagging (honestly, I've never seen the duplicate in that list unless it was already linked).

Improving this list would perhaps be step 1 of automating duplicate detection, but I doubt even a sophisticated machine learning program could properly mark duplicates whilst not consuming excessive resources.

Answer (score 3):

I would be shocked if anyone is using anything more than SO's built-in similar question detector.

As Lundin suggests in the comments, doing much better than the existing "similar questions" feature would probably require both domain knowlege and some form of [natural language understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_understanding). From what I've seen on SO, the difference between a novel question and blatant duplicate can often be as minor as *the context or combination(s) in which a problem or tool is being used*.

You might be able to train a traditional neural network to spot similar questions for a very specific technology (a specific SO tag, broadly speaking). That neural network would need a massive corpus of examples to train itself on, and would be useless for questions involving any other technologies. Plus, you would run into the chicken-and-egg problem of automatically deciding which specialized network is most appropriate for a given question (which means you would need some form of natural language understanding anyway).

A single neural network trained on every technology covered by SO would be so broad and generalized as to be useless. I have a hunch such a generalized network would wind up reinventing a poorly-performing fuzzy string matching algorithm anyway.

Unfortunately, an algorithm that can actually understand the text of a question seems to be considered an [AI Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete) problem.

**Note:** I am not even remotely an expert in the field of AI. Just an armchair hobbyist.