# Is there a specific penalty for suggested edit spam? Should I do anything about it other than rejecting it?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, spam

In the Suggested Edits queue, I just encountered (and rejected) an attempt by someone to add a spam link (a link to their own blog, with no disclosure of affiliation) to a tag wiki. The other reviewer who reviewed the suggested edit also caught the spam and also rejected it using the "Spam or Vandalism" reject reason.

When this happens, is there any specific penalty other than the rejected edit itself? Is there anything I should do to bring this to the attention of a moderator (e.g. flag one of the user's posts)?

Comment: I've considered editing a tag wiki with link to my tutorial and adding disclosure in edit summary.. but afraid to do so and also how'd the reviewer know it is good enough to be included? (unless the reviewer happens to be familiar with that topic)

Comment: @Sundeep I discovered the spam by observing that the suggested tag wiki edit was just adding a single link to a blog. I wondered, why just this blog? I went and looked at the blog and found that the blog's owner had a very similar name to the SO user proposing the edit *and* had the same profile picture. So, suggestions - do disclose affiliation (at least in the suggested edit summary, if not in the body), don't *just* add your link, improve the tag wiki in other ways, and explain *why* the link is valuable for tag wiki readers - don't just say it's an on-topic blog.

Comment: thanks for the input.. am not clear on disclosing affiliation in the body, can you give an example?(do you mean to add a note that the specific link was added by <link to my SO profile>?) regarding improving tag wiki, I did that and at last moment I bailed out on adding my link (another reason being not losing the significant edits I made just bcoz of additional link to my own tutorial).. adding a note why the link is valuable is good suggestion, probably should do it with already present links too

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consistently suggesting spam edits, and them being rejected as "spam or vandalism" does feed the user into the Spam Ram.

There are no automatically raised flags for those. If the user has been doing that continuously, do flag one of their posts. We'll send them a message. Similarly, if you find users approving them, do flag them as well, we'll send them off the review queues for a small amount of time.

From what I've seen, there will usually be just one spam edit and the spammer will move on. (Note that, just one rejected spam edit won't feed it to SpamRam)

Comment: The SE team has recently implemented a feature whereby links to spam rejected edits would show as fake 404 errors to logged-out users, so that spammers can't show whoever's paying them a public-facing page with spam, as this incentivized spammers to keep spamming via edits despite their edits getting rejected.

Comment: @gparyani FWIW this feature is explained in details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346542/839601)

Comment: @gparyani This is genius. The internet needs more fake 404 pages.

Comment: I've never heard of the Spam Ram. Do you have a link explaining what it is? [Google isn't turning up any results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Spam+Ram%22+stack+overflow) that readily look like they explain it.

Comment: @jpmc26 Spam Ram is Stack Overflow's internal spam fighting mechanism that does loads of secret stuff to block spam before it can be posted on site.  See this answer for some more details https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336289/4099593