# Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?

Tags: discussion, faq, downvotes, voting

I've been told not to assume that a specific person downvoted my post just because they commented at the same time the downvote came in.

Why not?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Came here to downvote this question, but after reading it I guess I'll just leave this comment (which DOES NOT correlate with a down-vote).

Comment: Same reason my wife should not assume I'm cheating because I came back home 30 minutes late. Two activities are 100% unrelated to each other and linking them under assumption is introducing unnecessary conflict. (Disclaimer: my wife never assumed that way)

Comment: strongly related: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/839601)

Comment: Useful to take the opposite: Why shouldn't I assume I know that someone upvoted my post?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

First, let's get this out of the way: Of *course* that's going to be your first instinct. It's only natural. But there are at least three reasons why making that assumption isn't useful:

1. **The assumption serves no positive purpose.** It doesn't help you in any way to make this assumption. In fact, it can easily lead you into taking actions with negative outcomes, such as making a negative comment to the person you think downvoted the post, which in turn can make that person (and others) look negatively on your conduct, which can color their view of your post (rightly or wrongly, humans are like that). A sufficiently vigorous negative comment may get flagged as offensive, and a series of such flags can impact your ability to post comments in the future, or may result in a [suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) from the site.
2. **Correlation is not causation.** Just because X happens before Y, it doesn't mean X *caused* Y, and it doesn't mean that X and Y have the same cause. Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. Lots of eyeballs on the same posts, lots of fingers on mice hovering over the same vote buttons. So it's not at all surprising if a post gets a vote and a comment from two completely unconnected people. (And don't rely on that "Viewed one time" indicator; it isn't updated while you sit on the page, and updates to it can be lazy.) I know from long experience of posting comments when someone else downvotes (or downvoting when someone else comments) and seeing this reaction that it's often not the same person. Someone downvoting may specifically decide *not* to make a comment at the same time, to avoid being assumed to be the downvoter.
3. **It's a distraction from the question you should be asking.** The real question shouldn't be "Why did X downvote my post?" but rather "Why did *someone* downvote my post?" which is effectively "What's wrong with my post?" *(by SO's standards)* which can be reformulated into "How can I improve my post?" Read the comment and decide if you think it's a valid critique. If it points you at a help page or similar, read the help page. Review the post with a critical eye to see if you can figure it out. If appropriate, post a comment asking what's wrong with it and/or how you can improve the post. (I've had good success with that when I've posted a duff answer. For whatever reason, two or three people will downvote, I'll fail to see why, ask, and someone will then helpfully point out what I've missed. The key is making the comment from the position of genuinely wanting to improve the post or understand why you should remove it, rather than a peeved way.)

Comment: For correlation != causation, I like to point to https://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - And of course, one of my faves: https://xkcd.com/552/

Comment: [552 explained](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/552:_Correlation).

Answer (score 8):

Additionally, it is worth noting that just because your answer was downvoted at the exact same time it was **edited** is certainly not a reason to assume the editor is the person who downvoted your post. Because whenever an **answer** (but not question) with a pending **very low quality** flag is edited, the flag will be automatically dismissed and the answer will automatically incur a downvote from the system for some reason.

So if person B flags your answer as VLQ, then person A edits it, and you notice that at the exact time person A edited it, the answer received a downvote, do not just assume that person A must have downvoted it, because it was in fact the community downvote incurred by editing an answer with a pending VLQ flag.

As for why the assumption **itself** is unhelpful, regardless its correctness, the [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388687/16217248) covers that nicely.

Comment: It is true. Spam flags downvote instantly, but VLQ flags downvote only after the answer was edited. It is not a very well-known feature but it is there. [Authoritative reference](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54784355).

Comment: That's a bug, right? Otherwise what's the rationale to auto-downvote after editing VLQ?

Comment: @tdy Strictly speaking, the downvote is caused by the VLQ flag _being marked helpful_.  An edit causes any VLQ flags on the post to be marked helpful, which in turn triggers the downvote.  In some sense, it's thus working as designed, but it's probably an unforeseen consequence of those two things interacting, and I personally question the value of the automatic downvote existing _at all_.

Comment: @RyanM Maybe it would be better if edits marked them as 'disputed' instead.

Answer (score -4):

Assumptions are what help us to make decisions every day, without needing to do the research to prove a causal relationship.  For example, Assumptions are made regularly by reviewers in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) based on external appearances of the post, by moderators handling flags for chatGPT or by users flagging posts.

So, why shouldn't you make an assumption that the user who commented is the user who downvoted?

You can. It's not a completely unreasonable assumption. But, what factors are you basing it on? If the only factor is timing once, that carries very little value.

The first few minutes of posting your question attracts many users. Many users simultaneously interact with your post in a public manner (comments, edits, answers, etc...) in the first few minutes. Because of conflict, Just the timing isn't enough to consider the user that took one action is the same user taking another action. For example, there was a case where a user who never downvoted once(cumulative votes are visible in profile) was accused of downvoting because of timing.

Correlation is not necessarily causation. It's just that two events can happen together coincidentally. However, correlation *can* indicate causation. To make an assumption that is much closer to the truth, you have to consider a combination of many factors.  For example, [Hill's criteria for causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradford_Hill_criteria) describe such factors. Some of these factors include:

- **Strength**
  The same user is involved in *many* of your posts + downvotes
- **Consistency**
  Involvement by the same user is almost always followed by downvotes almost always.
- **Specificity**
  Absence of involvement from the user results in no downvotes and upvotes.
- **Temporality**
  The user's action follows votes within a few seconds.
- **Plausibility**
  Negative or unconstructive comments by the user.

Now, if a few of these factors are true, then that *may* be a reason to assume you know who downvoted your posts, and if it's indeed malicious, you could even flag your post for moderator attention to get those votes reviewed as "targeted voting".

If not, and this is just a one-off, the assumption carries very little value. Downvoters are [not obligated and explicitly advised not to comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/).
If someone did comment voluntarily and constructively, it means they care about you and the post. They believe the post can be improved. You should be grateful for the comment and try to address the issues raised.

If the comment is rude/abusive/unkind/condescending or violates the [Code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) in any way, you can [flag it for moderator attention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging).

Comment: This doesn't read like a FAQ answer. It's a wall of text with quite a lot of bloat... It's rambly...

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Is there extra requirements for FAQ to be short? Could you provide a simple example, where a paragraph of text in my answer be be replaced with a simple line without removing the intended effect?

Comment: The easiest way to do so would be for me to edit this. I'll look into it in a while. It's not a _requirement_, but nobody looking at a FAQ wants to read a wall of text.

Comment: @Cerbrus For context, the accepted answer is ~460 words and this one has ~550 words. So, it is less than a 100 words more. And other FAQ questions regularly exceed 600 or more. So, I think it's not the length you're concerned about. You used "rambly" - So, I think you believe some text can be rewritten to give the same effect or do you have specific issue about some part? I wanted to see an example so that I may understand the issue first. You editing directly won't help me see it. But, as long as the intended meaning is not changed, I don't have qualms about your edits.

Comment: You're free to revert the edit, it's just too much to explain in comments.

Comment: @Cerbrus You don't have to explain it all. Just an example of one or two lines would suffice. But do ahead with the edits, if you think that's better. Thanks either way.

Comment: I've applied my edit, whew, 200 words less :D. You were bringing in a lot of other topics, like escalating stuff to SE, SOCVR, stuff that really isn't related to people downvoting the post. If you have questions about specific sections I removed, lemme know, @TheMaster.

Comment: @Cerbrus I believe some sections were necessary, so I added a simplified version of those sections to avoid deviating from the main topic. Thanks again for the edits.