# Why are my comments disappearing on my question?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Comments in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57993177/2016165) (if I remember correctly, not only mine) keep disappearing but I didn't delete them myself.

Is is possible that comments are deleted automatically if a word in them is on a blacklist? If they weren't deleted automatically, can anyone please restore them and tell me why they were deleted.

Here are the comments that were deleted (there were comments by others that were deleted by various moderators or those individuals; those are not included):

[image: First deleted comment from OP describes something they tried, the next calls a downvoter petty.]

Another...

[image: Comment from OP saying, "I'm not going to repeat myself".]

And another...
[image: Comment from OP calling an answerer condescending for asking the OP to do something unspecified before they answered.]

Comment: I'd hardly call it "random", it's the meta effect.

Comment: Sorry, meta effect? Is it normal that questions you link to here are downvoted?

Comment: It's normal that if you provide a link to a post to people who are more than willing to use the tools available to evaluate the post, they'll do so. It can result in votes in both directions, not just downvotes.

Comment: I meant "randomly" as in "downvote, even though there clearly wasn't enough time read the post and think about the question". Can I do anything about it apart from not posting here at all?

Comment: @rene Good to know, thanks. I understand that it's not openely visible to prevent abuse. I didn't swear in any of the comments and pretty sure the other person didn't either, so that's not it at least.

Comment: After looking at the deleted comments, you were pretty rude. That's reason enough to delete.

Comment: you really think your last comment was appropriate? like... Sincerely don't see anything wrong in what you said? (and remember: two wrongs don't make a right... So "he started it" isn't a good reason to write such comments).

Comment: What add-on or user script are you using to view those deleted comments and who deleted them? It seems odd that you're given a link to click to undelete a comment that was deleted at all, let alone one that was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @TylerH I provided the screenshot. Those are from my view of the deleted comments on a post.

Comment: ************ is me. I just recognized the "downvoting is petty" comment. Commenting on downvoting & insulting people who downvote cannot be accepted.

Comment: Not sure why the second one was deleted (it's still there). @Patrice No, I don't. That's exactly what the other guy did: He refused to give me an answer or even explain how to use/fix the code I found but instead kept demanding to see that I "understand" the functions first. If pointing out that someone is being a ***** is a problem, then how do you deal with it on here? Just flag the comments too?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There are now 5 downvotes, the first one because I didn't do what the guy demanded (I know he gave a different reason but we both know that that's just a "cover-up" because he downvoted directly after I commented). Then please tell me what's so wrong about this question that it justifies being downvoted that much.

Comment: Obviously I'm not the downvoters. But I'm pretty sure it's because of the meta effect. Summoning meta is a double-edged sword.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Kevin B already said that but how do you work against? Yesterday two of the downvotes were given 1-2 minutes after posting on meta, which clearly isn't enough time for read the whole question and form an opinion that justifies downvoting. So it looks like it was "downvoting for the sake of downvoting". If someone has a good reason to do it, okay, but just abusing the anonymous system like this is a problem!

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I assume who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/1233251).

Comment: I agree with that. But that's what happens 99% of the time when you complain on meta about a question that got closed/downvoted.@Neph

Comment: When you talk to people (who are trying to help you) like it's their fault and be mean to them, that's what happen. I am here now that just happened to me. I tried to help, she doesn't show any support. Expect us to write the full code for them(trying to copy someone's work and when that doesn't work). Then she flagged my comments. Show some respect to people who try to help. ( I not pointing to anyone here, just commenting here in cause someone finds it here by Google search.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your comments were deleted by moderators due to flags on your comments.

In most cases those comments were flagged as 'unfriendly or unkind' [by the system that flags these comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/16587).  In a few instances, they were flagged as "No Longer Needed", and deleted.

Comment: Okay, I worked out the flag-stuff so far but I don't understand the "unfriendly or unkind" flags, especially with multiple comments being gone. Do you see if the comments that were flagged as "no longer needed" were replies to other comments that had been deleted?

Comment: @neph they were both flagged correctly. The ones flagged as 'no longer needed' were obsolete.

Comment: Ad "no longer needed" - so a comment replying to a deleted comment? Ad "unfriendly" - sorry, not sure how any of my comments were unfriendly and why they would have been flagged as such.

Comment: @neph If you'd like, I can edit the comments that were deleted into your question. Typically we are loathe to share private action information unless you want us to.  Ultimately, unless a moderator reaches out in a private moderator message; it's nothing to worry about (we reach out when it becomes a pattern, not for the occasional frustration or outburst).

Comment: Could you please restore them and if they are indeed not needed anymore, I'll just delete them again tomorrow when I start working on the code again (or could you send me the text and I'll re-comment if necessary). Like I said, I kind of understand the "delete replies to deleted comments" flag (still sucks if it added infos though) but I'm still not sure why any of the comments would have been flagged as unfriendly. :/

Comment: @neph no. I agree with the moderator who deleted them.

Comment: Okay, edit it into my question then please. I still don't understand exactly what's going on though.

Comment: @Neph I've added screenshots; I've left the other moderator's name out of it; if they want to come forward they can, but reasonably I don't see a reason why they would need to.  I have left my name on the comments I deleted.

Comment: @jhpratt On purpose; also replaced it with further pruned screenshots. The originals contained comments deleted by their owners; which I didn't realize (and wouldn't have shown had I realized it -- since a moderator can't undelete comments deleted by their owner, it does no good to show them).

Comment: This seems like a really abuse-prone system. Mods can just delete comments with no trace they ever existed or who deleted them? At least the comment closing system lets you know what is happening.

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK, there is a "bad" comment prevention feature that blocks certain comments (it requires comments to have a minimum length, prevents posting certain phrases like "Thank you"), but once a comment is posted it requires at least one flag or moderator intervention to delete a comment.

---

Comments are not intended to be permanent. They could be flagged as "no longer required" among other options and if they got enough flags (sometimes only one flag is required) they will be deleted.

If there is something that should be permanent, add it to a question or answer. By permanent I mean that even if "comments" are later removed, they will still be available in the revision history even if the post is deleted as >10k rep users still could access them.

Comments doesn't have a revision history, <s>so there is no a regular way to recover them</s>. ♦ moderators could undelete comments but you should ask directly on the corresponding meta (in this case https://meta.stackoverflow.com) the guidelines to make an undelete comment request.

Another alternative is to create a chat room. Under certain circumstances a suggestion to move comments to a chat room will appear, but comments could be deleted before it appear, so if you don't want that a "good" comment be deleted, create the chat room in advance and add yourself the link to the chat room.

Related

- [Let us view our deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187279/289691)
- [How is it possible that a single user who is not a moderator can delete a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196435/289691)
- [Why can't I see moderator-deleted comments on my own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269974/289691)

Comment: Moderators can't always undelete comments; it depends on how they were deleted.  The only safe way to preserve content is to put it in a post (question or answer).

Comment: Thanks for the link. My last comment replied to the now very last comment, which is still there, so "no longer required" can't be the case. I have the suspicion that someone deleted it because they didn't like what I wrote. Is there a blacklist that automatically flags/deletes comments or is some type of human involvement always required?

Comment: Sorry, the commend replying to your post had just tipped over the 5 minute edit mark and I deleted and reposted it to add something. I just read your second link, thanks for that too. So, I guess someone must have flagged all the comments then, even though I'm not sure why. Am I right in my assumption that the threshold in the answer you linked is an interneral thing we can't see?

Comment: Sorry, another post, this time regarding your edit: None of the posts were "thank you" posts, it was always a reply to something. I had a case before where comments replying to other comments were deleted too and while this might have been the case with a couple of them this time (not sure tbh), it certainly wasn't with the very last comment (which is gone too).

Comment: @Neph Any comment can be deleted either by a mod, or in response to flags by normal users with the threshhold depending on the content of the comment. The only people that can give you more specific information about  your specific comments are the SO mods who can see the deleted comments and can usually give a good guess at least as to what caused their deletion.