# Is there an arbitration process regarding flagged comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags, deleted-comments

I did take a break of several years from answering, so I'm not really familiar with the latest fashion, but it seems to me that comments are deleted like crazy, and many of them despite being relevant to the answer, and not included in the answer edit. Am I wrong?

Is there a place were I can see why comments were deleted? Is there a place where I can appeal the deletion?

Comment: There is no way to view any deleted comments unless they were cached somewhere. This is where you appeal, perhaps a moderator will explain the situation.

Comment: Yeah, unless they're cached, it's not possible. If you happen to stumble over a bot that posted the comments in chat (pretty rare, usually only happens if it's perceived as heat by some bot). It might also be cached by some bot hooked up to the API, but beyond that, there's nothing you can do, and no way to see it. Only mods can see deleted comments on-site (it's not like answers and questions). Flagging, or as you already have, asking here are your options.

Comment: Lets go back a single step... is there anything useful on those comments that the OP can act on? Or were just "-1 this doesn't work"?

Comment: @Braiam, as clearly stated in the question, they were explaining why the approach is wrong. In this case I was stating that the use of grep is useless since he is creating an array just to filter out parts of it, when the same array can be easily constructed correctly from start. Anyway, I don't think that's the point of this discussion, please give me the benefit of the doubt and consider my characterization of the comments correct for this question. If a moderator wants to discuss them, then we can chat about it somewhere else, but that's not the point of this question.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at all, but it's best to try to comment on a post without discussing how you voted on it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I did't mention my down-vote in my comment, the author correctly assumed I did down-vote.

Comment: Moderators deleted your comments. You can ask about it here, which you’ve done. You can also ask us to paste your deleted comments into an answer or this question and we will do so. We won’t do it without your permission.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm not asking only about my comments, I'm asking about comments from other persons that were still relevant but they were removed. I doubt all of them were removed voluntarily, especialy since some of them were not included in the answer.

Comment: some comments were self-removed, others were removed by moderators. This applies for most removed comments BTW. Do you allow us to quote some of your comments?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, no because it's besides the point. My question is about the process not those specific comments. I'm not going to spend more time on those answers than I already spent.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, LOL if that is considered aggressive, I wonder if I shouldn't leave this site all togged. Also, nice on respecting my explicit request not to quote those.

Comment: yeah, I had second thoughts & deleted it, sorry! You were probably the only one to have read them. But it's NOT beside the point. It's difficult to answer your question without quoting anything BTW. It's too vague.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no, it isn't. I have accepted the answer, I do not consider the procedure OK, but since I decided it's time to move on, I don't really care too much to do something about it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389778/why-are-my-comments-disappearing-on-my-question this time comments were included on OP request.

Comment: As @Don'tPanic said, then why you explicitly stated that you downvoted it. Just post the pitfalls, no need to mention the votes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you know very well that this has nothing to do with that question, but you want to paint me as a villain by selecting some rude examples. This is a new low!

Comment: "by selecting rude examples": I just (briefly) quoted the comment of yours which started the war (there were rudest comments of yours...). How convienient from you to ask a question, play the victim and refuse that the comment timeline is shown... We moderators don't single out a particular person and make them a scapegoat, just for fun.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not talking about that mishap, I'm talking about you linking to a question that has only rude examples. And yes, we both know that you (moderators) overreach frequently - see the second example I gave, were you suspended me for "aggressively flagging comments" and then deleted those comments anyway. To simplify, I'm going to remove all the examples from my question, as they are just examples, and the question stands without them.

Comment: @Sorin Complaints like that are best addresed to the SE community team directly via the contact us link. Publicly griping about the mods in a unverifiable manner is unlikely to draw you any sympathy here.

Comment: @Magisch - complaint was raised on 15th, and successfully ignored by the SO team - ticket id 201909151301032288

Comment: @Sorin well there you go then. Wait until someone replies to your ticket.

Comment: @Magisch after 10 days, I wouldn't hold my breath

Comment: Keep in mind that editing the question does not remove the information from the site, only from what we see here - but we can go back to the original post. It seems to me, in the one case that disagrees with a posted answer, if the answer OP doesn't like the comments you'd be free to post your own answer, with a different approach and an explanation why the other approach is sub-optimal. That would be legitimate, but also open to DV, or course. But if you feel so strongly about it, that would be the way to ensure your opinion is clearly stated for all to read...

Comment: ...Since, as also stated by others in this exchange, comments are explicitly volatile/ephemeral and not guaranteed to remain on the site, I see no reason to complain about their removal or have an arbitration process. If someone needs to understand *why*, on order to be able to better comply with site guidelines, that would be different.

Comment: @CindyMeister, adding an answer would be acceptable, without the "Edit questions and answers" privilege. As you can clearly see from the second example, I already had an answer to that question, which the OP edited several times and in the end removing a part of the answer and copying it into his own. Frankly I don't have time to deal with that, nor do I have the calm required to remain under the ridiculous low bar for "aggressiveness" on SO.

Comment: @CindyMeister, since comments are considered volatile/ephemeral, why are the consequences so harsh ?

Comment: Which consequences? There are no mention of any consequences in any version of your question that I've looked at?

Comment: I didn't look at the second example, since the only description about that was some comments deleted for being rude, then others because they're no longer relevant. If an OP edits their question after it has received an answer, in such a way as to make the answer invalid, ***that*** needs to be brought to meta and/or to a moderator's attention. That is against the site's rules...

Comment: ...Better to do that as soon as you notice someone is not going to "play nice", rather than get into a comment and/or editing war. Bring it to the attention of the community, then try to forget it if time/nerves-leading-to aggressiveness is a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The arbitration process is you ask a question on meta about why it happened. You can also reach out to the community team if you think your comments are deleted unfairly. If you ask us to, we will include the text of the comments and what caused them to be deleted.

We won’t do so without your permission, as we believe the deletion is the sum total of the moderation action and see no benefit to “airing dirty laundry”.

Comment: Since some of the deleted comments weren't mine, this isn't going to work.  For example, for the second answer, my issue e is that the moderators deleted several relevant comments that weren't mine.

Comment: @Sorin Doesn't really matter whose comments they are for the "how do I request review" part... and there's generally no reason to hide comments if a mod deleted them, assuming they're not profane. If the poster deleted them, however, there's no reason to post the content since they were deleted intentionally by the commenter.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are meant to be lightweight and perhaps ephemeral. Adding an arbitration process would make dealing with them more work.