# My comments below my answer are repeatedly deleted - what is going on here?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

A few days ago one user started a discussion about my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json/55850752#55850752). Some of their comments I feel were unkind so I flagged them and they were deleted.

However after that my comments (which I feel were neutral) start to be deleted too. This situation happened over ~3 days - [here is a screenshot](https://prnt.sc/pbtl6l) which I made today with comment that is currently deleted (why?). I can't have a discussion on my own answers.

Why? What is going on there?

Comment: Multiple moderators deleted comments for multiple reasons. I’m on mobile otherwise I’d post a more in depth answer now. May do so later.

Comment: or I can steal your thunder and do it now on your behalf using my ergonomic keyboard & mouse & 22 inch screen :)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: Mechanical keyboard (Cherry)?

Comment: [IBM RS6000 AIX](https://dqzrr9k4bjpzk.cloudfront.net/images/17925090/1130013561.jpg), the best ones, with horrible clicking sounds.

Comment: Note that the question is more than 11 years old (nothing wrong with that), but late answers are (unfortunately) often downvoted. Why did you take the risk? Especially starting out (first revision) with non-standard English - to the casual reader this invariably comes across as a lazy low-quality answer attempting to fish for easy reputation points (whether it is or not).

Comment: To counter the (unfortunate) bias, late answers need to be of extraordinary high quality, both in content and presentation. And comprehensive (e.g. with runnable example code / tests and test / example data). And not repeating previous answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You flagged comments from another person and those comments (which were rude for the most part) were deleted by moderators.

Your comments were trying to reply to those comments. Once the rude comments were deleted, your comments stood there, meaningless. They were deleted by a moderator too (without any hidden penalty held against you).

Note that if the comments don't contain obviously rude words or notoriously noisy things like "thank you", only moderators can easily delete them, either directly, or if someone flags them as "no longer needed" (enough "no longer needed" flags by non-moderators [also deletes comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/382678), but that's not what happened here anyway)

So don't worry about those. You're not crazy, you really wrote those, and they weren't rude or abusive (or we would have notified you by now), just noise once the above matter was settled.

Just don't ask why your comments were deleted: moderators did that to remove the noise. If you want to add something that remains in the Q&A, just edit your answer instead. And if someone is rude/condescending, just flag and don't reply. No need to feed trolls.

Related (and posted recently):

- [Is there an arbitration process regarding flagged comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389781/is-there-an-arbitration-process-regarding-flagged-comments)
- [Why are my comments disappearing on my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389778/why-are-my-comments-disappearing-on-my-question)

Comment: I think three "no longer needed" flags from non-moderators still auto-delete comments.  At least I recall they used to, and if [the FAQ post is up to date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/160551), that may not have changed.

Comment: you are right. I didn't take time to check the site docs. Edited

Comment: Also, when a comment meet some parameters, they can also be deleted by a single flag.

Comment: "some parameters". Yes. Rude words, or "thanks", things like that.