# What should you do if someone goes after your previous questions to downvote them?

Tags: discussion, reputation

For some reason after I answered a question today (not sure which one), it seems like someone entered my profile and just downvoted two very old questions.

[image]

I highly believe this is what happened because I never got downvoted on two old questions at the same time, Honestly I don't remember having one single question being downvoted after so long.

So I think this was directed, probably by someone trying to get points after seeing I got an accepted answer before them.

How does Stack Overflow deal with this?

Comment: I'm afraid that two downvotes aren't enough to make a pattern. There are ways to handle this when there is a stronger signal, but little can be done here.

Comment: Two votes? It doesn't. Two votes doesn't trip the system, nor does it get reverted manually.  I've tried several times on bulks of two downvotes several times, but nothing ever happened. Annoyingly, serial upvotes I flagged haven't been reverted either, so that's annoying xd There's not really anything you can do aside reviewing them and cleaning them up for good measure.

Comment: Yeah doing some research it sounds like serial voting, which is common in here apparently. It's just weird that someone would do that out of whatever reason they had.

Comment: Sure, but at the same time there is no evidence that the votes were merely cast as an attempt to harm you personally. It makes sense to investigate if the downvotes keep coming in such a way that it's clearer that something is not right.

Comment: Most of the time you get serial votes, you've usually pissed someone off, and most of the time, it's retaliation for moderation or because you downvoted a post and left a comment, or because someone thinks you downvoted an answer... Some people just want revenge for all kinds of weird reasons. I'll never understand why, but this happens from time to time to most of us - although some people get more dedicated revenge downvoters than others and get enough to get it reverted. To put it like this, you're in good company :')

Comment: @Zoe yeah in my case, I reviewed my actions for today and all I can think of is one question where I answered and got accepted, and there were other two answers. I think it could be one of them lol

Comment: StackOverflow's race of who answers faster to get more points is really weird and counterintuitive.

Comment: Please note that 2 downvotes may as well mean - I see strange answer... let's see if that person has pattern of those (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984841/x/62984864#62984864 - which is just answer to typo question)... ohhh there are more of those. I'd better stop right now and add the author to *the little black book*. I'm not saying that this is indeed the case here, but writing downvotes off instantly as "those just don't like me" may potentially limit ways to learn...

Comment: Two votes is not a pattern. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post

Comment: Stack Overflow is, ***by design***, competitive and ego-driven. One drawback is seen here. Others are mob downvoting and [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533). If Stack Overflow Inc really wants it to be more welcoming, they should redesign the software (e.g. to be more collaborative and less competitive/ego-driven).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I understand. I've been answering stuff here since 2016 so I'm well aware of the community guidelines and I'm aware some of my older answers/questions might be bad. This specific one you listed is not just a typo, the user just didn't understand how the language works so I thought I'd answer it but I know those can just be marked as typo or duplicate.