# When answering, should we upvote the question and the other (correct) answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, upvotes, etiquette

When answering a question on Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites, I usually upvote both the question, as well as any other answers on the question that correct and working. My reasoning is the following:

- For the question: If the question is worth your time to answer it, it means that it meets the minimum requirements for a good question, i.e. it is interesting, well formed, on topic and answerable. Thus, it probably deserves an upvote.
- For the other answers: If you are answering the question, it means that you have some knowledge on the topic, so you are in a good position to evaluate the correctness of the other answers. So if they work correctly without violating best practices, then they probably deserve an upvote.

Upvoting both the question and the answers also raises the 'hotness' of the thread, which may lead the question to be included on lists such as the 'Hot Network Questions' list, leading to more views and more upvotes on your answer as well.

It also spreads good vibes to the fellow contributors, encourages more good content and more participation, and helps rate good content.

However, I have noticed that many people answering, upvote neither the question nor the other answers. While I understand that it is the option of any user to upvote anything they want or nothing at all, I don't really understand why this happens.

So the question is, should we upvote the question and the "competing" correct answers when answering the question? It you don't upvote them, why don't you?

Comment: *"i.e. it is interesting, well formed, on topic and answerable. Thus, it probably deserves an upvote."* - Why should that mean it deserves an upvote? The upvote tooltip says: *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"* I can only gauge if a question is useful to me personally, I'm sure questions are useful to other people, but that's unhelpful for me, because of that, I'll upvote questions that _I_ find useful, it being answerable by me likely means I it's not useful to me, and not worth an upvote.

Comment: I often downvote questions that I answer...

Comment: @Dharman: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more in an answer, because your comment seems a bit contradictory: If the question downvote worthy, doesn't it mean that it shouldn't have been posted, and thus shouldn't be answered?

Comment: Downvote does not mean that the question should not have been answered. It only means that it's unlikely to be helpful to many people. Are you confusing downvotes with close votes?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine: It's interesting that you vote on questions based on whether it is helphul to *you*, but Dharman votes based on what he thinks is helpful to *many people*. It seems that people interpret the meaning of votes in vastly different ways. The point of this question was to have a discussion on the voting habits and to understand better how and why people vote on questions and answers.

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't think that the duplicates answer this question completely. The questions you linked are all about upvoting the question, this question is also about upvoting the other answers on the question.

Comment: You would have preferred that I close as lacking focus, then, since you asked two different questions rolled into one? I can accommodate that, but I generally prefer to close questions as duplicates where possible, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: i wouldn't upvote if i was holding a cigarette in my hand; the one that i use the mouse with. is this enough reason?

Answer (score 4):

The rule of thumb is always to vote based on your **personal quality assessment** of each post.

And I could end the answer here, as everything else derives from this, but here is an expansion.

> However, I have noticed that many people answering, upvote neither the question nor the other answers. While I understand that it is the option of any user to upvote anything they want or nothing at all

It is the choice of each user to decide what to do upon a question and its answers. There is not much to reason about how votes are placed in these circumstances, other than discussing about encouraging votes in a more general perspective (e.g. [encouraging downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting)). We should let each user take part on voting as they see fit. It is worth noting that you should not be [trying to identify who is voting on what](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post) in any case.

---

But ultimately, I think the confusions which raised this Meta question in the first place were:

- Unfortunately, some people do not use votes based on what they were designed to do, and even take pride in voting based criteria which are at best tangential to this quality assessment. This includes votes to counter other votes, voting or refraining from voting based on whether the user is new, and so on. Do not be mistaken. This is very frowned upon, since it does not contribute to the platform's body of information.
- *Each person's standards of quality differ.* For many users of the platform, it is enough for a question to seem *interesting* or legitimate to merit an upvote. On the other hand, one might easily argue that the question's legitimacy does not make it useful. A answer may be correct, but that does not always mean that it is valuable.
- Quality *cannot be isolated* to a single post. The presence of other answers in the same question, and even other pieces of content on the wider Web, does affect how well received a new answer will be. In the event that it just repeats an existing answer or the official documentation, there is little gained from that. In the latter case, that is also a sign of poor research effort from the asker.

Comment: *"For many users of the platform, it is enough for a question to seem interesting or legitimate to merit an upvote."* That's pretty much what the tooltip says are reasons for upvoting, so it seems like a good thing users of the platform are using that standard when voting. Of course, it is true that quality standards differ for a variety of reasons, but it sounds like you're implying it's misguided to upvote questions strictly because they seem interesting or legitimate; I don't think that's true. *"Quality cannot be isolated to a single post."* Err, what? Yes. That's the whole idea of voting.

Comment: @CodyGray Many users end up asking a question precisely because they have stumbled upon a problem in their work. I imagine most question are of this kind. Despite the supposed validity of the question, it may still be unclear, lack important details, or just not useful in other ways. As such, I find such a characteristic to be a low bar for an upvote. Then again, personal assessments may differ.

Comment: @CodyGray on the second matter, the two example stated in the answer should be clear why a quality assessment cannot be isolated on itself, just as communities and libraries do not live in pure isolation (unless censorship is involved, which we disregard here).

Comment: Hmm. I cannot agree that a question which is unclear and/or lacks important details is either valid or useful. So, yeah, that would not meet my minimum criteria for an upvote. But that is clear simply by reading the question in isolation, without any additional context being required.

Comment: Surely, if a question is unclear and/or lacks important details it should *not* be answered until it's fixed. If a question is answerable but it has minor flaws that don't prevent a good answer from being written, then help the OP to fix it, or edit it yourself. The system even rewards you with badges for timely editing of questions that you answer.