# Abnormal activity on one of my questions

Tags: support, specific-question

I want to report a past abnormal activity. In this question:

[Why does subclassing in Python slow things down so much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912147/why-does-subclassing-in-python-slow-things-down-so-much)

with also many downvotes (4). I say "abnormal activity", but I think the right term is attack.

The attack was moved after this discussion:
https://www.mail-archive.com/search?q=Problems+with+dict+subclassing+performance&l=python-dev%40python.org

1. Are these activities legit?
2. Can't the users involved be sanctioned in any way?

Comment: It was used as an audit, that likely attracted some weird attention. There's no users that need be sanctioned if they're just voting the way they feel they should for the given post.

Comment: Yes, an audit, as in it was used in the review queues to see if people are paying attention. Presumably people clicked through to the real question and voted on it directly. :shrug: You can see it in the timeline for the post.

Comment: Yes... as i said it's in your post timeline. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59912147/timeline Given you have no access to who casted the votes, there's no evidence you could possibly have...

Comment: I would argue the "abnormal activity" is the upvotes it received. That's *far* more abnormal than the downvotes.

Comment: The downvotes also came *after* the time that you note in your question, which was a bit after the audits ended... more than a year later.

Comment: FWIW, I find the question very hard to digest. The first "code" block is a huge dump of raw shell input/output covering shell commands, pyperfs overly detailed diagnostics, quoted Python code, and an interactive Python shell. That the prose is written in a journal style with two **Edit** sections mixing the question with your own investigation doesn't help matters either. This really doesn't make an "attack" the only viable motivation for downvotes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi please read this link: https://www.mail-archive.com/search?q=Problems+with+dict+subclassing+performance&l=python-dev%40python.org

Comment: @MarcoSulla I did. Very entertaining. Doesn't change that the question has serious issues.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The fact is that is evident the downvotes was not cast for the quality of the question, but for merely personal reasons. That link is an evidence. About the quality of the question, how can I improve it?

Comment: @MarcoSulla Well, splitting and reformatting the code block so that each part is readable and getting rid of the journal style with two **Edit** sections would be a start.

Comment: You keep saying “evidence“… https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk

Comment: *"The fact is that is evident the downvotes was not cast for the quality of the question, but for merely personal reasons."* How do you know who voted, and why? I can't speak for anyone other than myself, but I never excelled at telepathy.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ok about the journal style, but I have not understood how must I split and reformat the code block. It's a bash output, where should I split it and how must I reformat it?

Comment: @vandench It was evident because I saw the downvotes when the discussion was going on. 4 downvotes are not a coincidence. I think a MOD can see the dates.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Splitting it into separate blocks for each "part" - the python and pyperf info, the pyperf command line runs, and finally the interactive timeit runs - would be a start. Actually, dropping the pyperf info or at least moving it to the end would help immensely as well; otherwise the entire first page of the question is just auxiliary information.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, the style of the question had no part in the downvotes, that was four, done in the same span of time and during the linked discussion. 4 downvotes at the same time is not a coincidence and it's very hard to convince someone that were not casted because of the discussion.

Comment: @MarcoSulla "the style of the question had no part in the downvotes" I don't see how one can assert that. There were definitely other possible reasons for downvotes and you literally cannot know who voted and why.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I know the number of downvotes, the time they was casted and the fact they time coincide with the discussion. 4 downvotes at the same time is *not* a coincidence.

Comment: It is strange that you don't complain about the additional upvotes you got during the time span when your question got more attention.

Comment: @MarcoSulla - Just because you were having a discussion, with individuals outside of SO, who happened to vote on your question does not mean those 4 votes are illegitimate. Unless you will also want the upvotes from those same users, outside of SO, who upvoted your question to be reversed.

Comment: Users can vote however they want for any reason they want, with the exception of serial voting and voting rings. This isn't either of those, so even if you could somehow prove your suspicions it still wouldn't get the votes reversed.

Comment: What **specifically** indicates to you that the downvotes were cast because of you being the author? If there's something specific in the 54 messages found in the search you've linked which you feel indicates that the votes were cast for inappropriate reasons, then please *explicitly state* what that is and link directly to the message(s) in which such statements were made. It's not reasonable to expect us to go read 54 messages looking for something which you haven't *specifically* described.

Comment: I'd note that during that time you did things which drew quite a bit of additional attention to your question. Thus, it's expected that the additional attention will result in more votes (upvotes and/or downvotes) that are just based on the larger volume of people's impression of the question at that time. Note: I have not done any evaluation of the question or that thread from the standpoint of being a moderator. I'm primarily saying that you need to provide more detailed information prior to someone else looking into this.

Comment: Please see: "[What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](/q/252270/3773011)", "[What to do when massive downvoting hits you due to an external source?](/q/318863/3773011)", and "[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/271271)", along with "[What is the meta effect?](/q/269349/3773011)" and '[What is the "meta effect"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/271271)'. As to the "meta effect" being relevant: those describe what generally happens when more attention is drawn to a post.

Comment: To be clear: The proper way to report voting issues is to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag or use the [Contact Us link](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact/) located at the bottom of every page. Other than people helping you focus your inquiry, as did happen here, there's really nothing that regular users can do about voting issues and posting about such issues on meta tends to be detrimental in multiple ways, due to the meta effect. I'm not saying there's not an issue here (I haven't investigated). I'm saying that a meta post isn't the way to report such issues.

Comment: @Makyen thank you for the information, I simply do not know that.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't get any upvote to that question after that discussion.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Didn't you get an upvote on Aug 17?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I had to search in my history, since I was going with my rememberings until now. Yes, I had a single upvote on Aug 17. On the contrary, I got four downvotes on Aug 16, 17, 18 and 23. The time is the same as the discussion and I never got a downvote before. This is not a coincidence. And I don't care about the downvotes, I want only that the authors will pay for their abuse, and for that I'll use the Contact Us as Makyen suggested to me.

Answer (score 15):

Between 2020-01-28 and 2020-02-25, [your question was used as an Audit in the review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59912147/timeline). During this period, your question may have received more views due to people clicking through to it as well as more voting activity. During this month-long period, your question received 2 upvotes, 0 downvotes.

More than a year later, in August 2021, you received 4 downvotes and 2 upvotes over ~23 days. This timeline corresponds with [you opening up a ticket in the python bug tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912147/why-does-subclassing-in-python-slow-things-down-so-much#comment121631973_59914459).

I don't see anything malicious about any of this activity.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But the downvotes was done deliberately as a personal attack. Is there nothing SO can do against the users and/or the downvotes?

Comment: votes can be reversed, but given that requires both mods and CMs, and proof they were casted for malicious reasons, it's very unlikely 4 people's votes will be reversed due to casting a single vote each. They certainly wouldn't be actioned in any way for something that happened 2+ years ago...

Comment: `They certainly wouldn't be actioned in any way for something that happened 2+ years ago` Why? The statute of limitations maxed out? :D

Comment: Put another way, while its certainly possible people viewed your opening of the ticket as an attempt to attract attention to your SO question, and thus upvotes, even if users felt that way that's not evidence that the purpose of their vote wasn't because they felt the question wasn't useful or was low quality... both of which are valid reason to downvote. Now, if at the same time you received downvotes on other questions of yours? that's a reason to raise a mod flag,

Comment: It's clear from the discussion that the downvotes was done for merely personal reasons: https://www.mail-archive.com/search?q=Problems+with+dict+subclassing+performance&l=python-dev%40python.org

Comment: users being upset isn't evidence they didn't also see the question as not useful.

Comment: 4 users at the same time is not a coincidence.

Comment: @MarcoSulla - So use the “Contact Us” link, provide details about the behavior, but there is absolutely no real proof those downvotes were not legitimate. You linked to your question at GitHub issue page which means everyone that ever opened that issue could have voted on your question.

Comment: @MarcoSulla - Just because they were me personal doesn’t mean they were not legitimate votes. You all behave like a bunch of clowns in that archive mailing list discussion, that discussion, was totally off the wall. The only way those votes would be reversed is if you were serially voted or the user used multiple accounts to cast multiple votes. Upvotes and downvotes would be reversed.

Comment: "But the downvotes was done deliberately as a personal attack." - **please read**: [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/)

Comment: @SecurityHound `You all behave like a bunch of clowns in that archive mailing list discussion` Well, sorry if I tried only to be helpful to the Python community, and all I had get was insinuations to be a climber, a ban and an assault to my SO question, that simply tried to understand a problem. I find nothing hilarious in this.