# Can I have a list or be allowed to view my deleted posts so I can fix my question ban?

Tags: support, status-completed, post-ban

I'm wondering if somebody with the reputation/ability can post some URLs to any of my older deleted posts. From what I understand the only way to view them is to have <10K Rep and/or the URL and I have neither. I have been trying to dig myself out of a question ban for some time, gaining reputation slowly and answering questions as I can but nothing is changing. I'm hoping I can revise some of my older posts.

Thank You,

PS: When is my 6 Month question ability mark?

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/55391672) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/50789914) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/42461262) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/42459615) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/42451376) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/42036419) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/40116851) [8](//stackoverflow.com/q/33993108) [9](//stackoverflow.com/q/32089462))

Comment: Deleted answers, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/a/56544460) [2](//stackoverflow.com/a/38154913) [3](//stackoverflow.com/a/34543838) [4](//stackoverflow.com/a/34540479) [5](//stackoverflow.com/a/33140896))

Comment: Find your most recently asked question (whether it's deleted or not) and add 6 months. That's when you can ask the next one unless you improve your existing questions sufficiently that you get unbanned of course.

Comment: Simple Enough will do!

Comment: Looking through your questions, most (all?) lack a clear focus (one concern per question), clear problem formulation, MCVE, research -- the attributes that are required for an answer useful for future readers. Please take time to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help or you aren't going to get far, either here or elsewhere at SE.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/ is also a good reference of typical mistakes that askers make.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Yes questions like this one I I would have preferred to post it on stackoverflow.com clearly show no research effort. https://superuser.com/a/1495453/465645 it's not like I read posts on stack Overflow and MSDN.com and found a problem with a post on stack overflow. Also the code I gave was hardly reproducible right?. How can I be top 14% on SO and also such a bad contributor that I'm worth Banning. Appreciate your feedback but to compare stack Overflow to the rest of the SE network is not fair. SE in general is a great tool and a very welcoming community but SO reminds me of ....

Comment: I have learned a lot since joining stackoverflow.com and I'm much better at making MCVE positively contributing to this website. Personally I think the algorithm needs to be adjusted if I can't learn to grow both and skill and with this site its needs adjustment. I'm not part of the 1% of amazing coders but I know my stuff. Perhaps we need a similar comparison to SU and Server fault. A place where newbies can post and where real devs cab post and each Community will grow for its own reasons.

Comment: Good thing you're willing to learn -- then there's hope for you :-) SO is negative because it gets so much more traffic than other SE sites that existing tools can't cope with keeping the quality up. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262791/the-rudeness-on-stack-overflow-is-too-damn-high

Comment: Trust me, I've been using stack Overflow to try and learn VBA and also remove my question ban by giving answers to VBA tag questions..... 99% of everything I see is posted by users with one rep and it's a horrible question to be honest... I do get that reasoning for stack Overflow being more brutal so to speak. I'm fairly confident I'll get out of this ban and hopefully not get banned again but I have to be honest most people vote on answers not questions which leaves me in a pickle. I will always vote on both if I vote on an answer I will vote on the question doesn't mean that they're always

Comment: My work doesn't exactly know they're paying me for this :P, but they do reap the benefits.

Comment: VBA is likely the reason you've been banned; the tag is historically insanely low quality, so the few frequenters are super quality minded.  It's hard to find good questions among the junk.

Comment: Welp, the "Meta-Effect" seems to have gotten me unbanned, which was not my intention, I will still look at any old posts I can fix. Here is the question that was motivating me recently to get unbanned, hope it's good quality :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600980/collapsing-pivotfield-with-duplicate-occurance-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 9 deleted questions on Stack Overflow. They are as follows:

- [Excel Macro that Runs Once and Never Again and is Distributed via XLAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391672/excel-macro-that-runs-once-and-never-again-and-is-distributed-via-xlam)
- [Calling Macro from inside Macro - Error Compile Error: Expected variable or procedure, not module - Private Sub App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789914/calling-macro-from-inside-macro-error-compile-error-expected-variable-or-proc)
- [PHP Zip - filesize(): stat failed for file.zip - readfile(file.zip): failed to open stream: No such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461262/php-zip-filesize-stat-failed-for-file-zip-readfilefile-zip-failed-to-o)
- [For Loop in PHP PDO Statement only returning one result when expecting multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459615/for-loop-in-php-pdo-statement-only-returning-one-result-when-expecting-multiple)
- [Storing PHP PDO Results into Variable(s) [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451376/storing-php-pdo-results-into-variables)
- [If my company pays someone to write code, do we own the rights to the final product? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036419/if-my-company-pays-someone-to-write-code-do-we-own-the-rights-to-the-final-prod)
- [Restrict LDAP SSH Access to Group - CentOS 7 Client - authconfig [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116851/restrict-ldap-ssh-access-to-group-centos-7-client-authconfig)
- [OpenVPN IPTABLES/Server Config Issues - DNS/DHCP - Can Mount Shares but not view - Can SSH via LAN IP into Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993108/openvpn-iptables-server-config-issues-dns-dhcp-can-mount-shares-but-not-view)
- [Exporting a Variable with a Variable inside the relys on a FIND statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089462/exporting-a-variable-with-a-variable-inside-the-relys-on-a-find-statement)

<strike>I cannot see when you are next eligible to ask a question. I do not believe that information is made available to moderators.</strike> [According to Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390804/view-deleted-posts#comment737567_390804), determining when you are next eligible to ask a question is as simple as finding your most recently-asked question (whether it's deleted or not), and then adding 6 months. This is so simple and obvious that it must be correct. In your case, your most recent question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048421/break-batch-if-else-statement-into-multiple-lines-hard-to-read-code), asked on May 8, 2019, so you would next be eligible to ask a question on November 8, 2019—assuming that you didn't find a way to dig yourself out of a question ban by then by improving your existing contributions.

You are not currently blocked from answering. You are only blocked from asking questions.

Obligatory link: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)