# Question says duplicate "already has an answer" but it doesn't

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730365/first-order-logic-conjunctive-normal-form-representation

has been flagged as a dupe, and the box says:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

but the dupe, which is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687504/first-order-logic-tools

does not have an answer, and I don't think it ever did (nor ever will).

Is "This question has been asked before and already has an answer" an error, a write-in value, a misjudgment on the reason for close, or something else?

I think the OP may have got confused because they may have read this and thought "ooh, my duplicate question has an answer!" and then gone "hey, where's my answer?" on the other post.

This situation seems similar to (but not a duplicate of) this but with a more definite assertion of the existence of the answer:

["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166537/marked-as-duplicate-text-doesnt-make-sense-for-questions-that-have-no-answer

Comment: Also see [Meta duplicates don't require an answer. Don't suggest there is one when that's not true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189782) and ["Closed as Duplicate" text is misleading when the duplicate is from the same user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190527)

Comment: [atleast you didn't get redirected to something that doesn't exist offering answers!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265640/why-isnt-the-duplicate-closure-lifted-when-the-original-post-is-deleted)

Comment: Also of interest: [Duplicate question changes - can't mark duplicates by same user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/duplicate-question-changes-cant-mark-duplicates-by-same-user).

Answer (score 33):

There is an exception in the system where we get to close dupes to a post **by the same author**; no answer is required to exist on the other post in such cases.

The question you link to was reposted by the same user, which is pointless. It was thus closed as a duplicate.

As with many exceptions, it is not worth complicating what is meant to be a terse notice. In other words, this is not a bug.

Comment: The notice is terse but wrong. The question does not "already have an answer". If the notice said "may have an answer" or just said it was a duplicate and nothing about its answered state, I wouldn't see a problem.

Comment: The original question is not available anymore. Does the duplicate still make sense then?

Comment: @Trilarion: the original was off-topic, the new one is no more on-topic. There is little point in resurrecting it.

Comment: These kinds of duplicates should be deleted or merged.

Comment: @Raedwald: Posts like those end up auto-deleted anyway; posts with a negative score and no answers that are not locked are cleaned up after 30 days.