# Why isn't the duplicate closure lifted when the "original" post is deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, migration

I've been going through some old posts when i found a question marked as duplicate as shown below:

[image: duplicate]

(*This post isn't particularly about that question*)

When I clicked the link provided to see the original answer, I was welcomed by the `Page Not Found` page.

> [image: page not found]

One interesting thing about this is the close reason:

[image: close reason]

As you can see it says

> "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question".

Obviously might be what the OP did..? Anyway even if not, shouldn't it say something or like

"For re-opening this question please update it properly to distinguish it from the other one" ..?

posting new similar questions while the duplicate exists forever doesn't seems like a perfect solution to me, isn't it simply adding more noise? Well, Forget that part.

My real question is, why isn't it re-opened when the original question, which claimed to have answers is deleted and no longer exists..? It isn't a duplicate anymore and leading someone to a `Page Not Found` page offering solutions doesn't seem to be a good thing for me...

**Reply to accepted answer:** My suggestion is to lift the closure and mark the *previously original post* as duplicate in case if it is if it is un-deleted, So that users won't try to take advantage of this.

This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059475/html-tags-not-working-inside-switch-case/22062328#22062328) I was referring to if it's required.

Comment: This user is the author of both questions.  He posted the exact same question twice, and then deleted the older question when his newer question was closed as a duplicate of it.  Personally I'd say that both questions should really be deleted...

Comment: @Servy personally i'd say the same about *this question* too... Like i said, this isn't particularly about that question... i was wondering why system is designed such a way that it allows leading someone to a 404...

Comment: Because in the general case the system doesn't know what *should* happen.  Perhaps the question should be deleted, perhaps it should be reopened, perhaps it should be closed for some other reason, etc.  Realistically some human person really needs to evaluate the situation to determine what should happen.  Automatically reopening it is simply going to be the wrong chose often enough that you certainly can't just do that automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because deletion is not permanent, mostly. Otherwise someone reposting their question could endlessly spam the site; every time someone closed their post as a duplicate, they could simply delete, then undelete their older question, and hey, *presto*, dupe banner gone.

This was a user reposting the question, always a no-no. In this case, simply vote to reopen, with a quick comment to state that the OP had re-posted the same question, but that the earlier copy is now deleted.

Comment: So nothing (garbage like closed questions, duplicates, deleted Q & A) will be actually deleted from SO as long as it exists..? i was thinking more like something will happen to deleted posts after 2 months... :|

Comment: @TilwinJoy: no, no post is ever really deleted, except in very specific circumstances (revisions with passwords / security sensitive info spring to mind).

Comment: How about lifting the closure and marking the *previously original* post as duplicate if it is un-deleted..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy: Because we don't want to award such behaviour either. The OP would get a free unlock post by deleting the other one. Remember that the first post has had longer to gather downvotes too.

Comment: You seem to be talking about the particular low quality question. I was simply suggesting in general, since there are actually duplicate questions with quality answers which we often find from google searches...

Comment: @TilwinJoy: Those are rare enough that moderators can handle those after being alerted by an 'other' moderator flag though.

Comment: Delete old question, create new one, get answer, undelete old question. Does it work?

Comment: @JimmyT.: and what would that achieve? They already got their answer. And deleting downvoted questions is a faster ticket to the question block.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant that someone who wants to create a question which would be probably marked as duplicate could do that. They could do it if they want to ask a slightly diffrent question.

Comment: @JimmyT.: If the other question has no answers, they can do so. But again, such tricks are only going to go so far before they are either flagged for moderator attention or otherwise dealt with automatically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Still works better than leaving the other question open.