# Flood of plagiarized wiki edits

Tags: support, spam

A user is creating a ton of tag wiki edits like the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5467770

The several I've spot-checked seem to be copied verbatim from random web pages (usually but not always related ones). Most are being robo-accepted.

Normally I'd flag this sort of thing, but I have no idea how to attach a flag to a tag wiki.

Comment: That user created the tags and edited them after... can't you create a tag with a description??

Comment: yes, they've created quite a bit of /review work on tags that only have a single question. It is tempting to prevent tag wikis on tags that have less than, say, 10 questions. Thoughts?

Comment: And he did that on August 1st too... fun history to check. Acutally, he's been at that for a while, his Activity history is filled up with tags creation/changes. Back to December 4th...

Comment: @MarcGravell I dunno... I can definitely see why a developer might want to jump-start their relatively young product's tag wiki, and I wouldn't think them wrong to do it.

Comment: @Sneftel: According to current sentiment, it is wrong. First, get enough genuine questions going to warrant a tag (no fudging there please), than create the tag. A single question (or less than a handful), does not warrant tag-creation in most cases.

Comment: @MarcGravell That seems very reasonable.

Comment: @MarcGravell: ... or just stop people from having more than *x* posts in the suggested edit queue at a time. Sneftel has a valid use case for creating wikis for < 10 tag q's, and arguably, when a tag is new is when we should be saying what it can/ can't be used for.

Comment: Not again with the Tag Wiki copy/paste complaints.  It's an excerpt, and a very short one at that.  Fair Use doesn't apply?  I'd be more concerned about suggestions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5468133), which isn't even correct, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5468121), which doesn't impart any useful information.

Comment: I assume this specific case is used for raising reputation. As you can see on his profile reputation changes each edit gives +2 to reputation. As many people to find jobs give their SO profile links, I think this may be related. As possible solution - no reputation for wiki edits?

Comment: What worries me is that people actually approved the mentioned tag [pseries] That description doesn't explain anything to me. But that might be me.

Comment: @Sneftel If someone would like to jump-start a new tag wiki, but prefer not to wait for ten questions to be asked, they could provide ten "seed" self-answered questions.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250613/mass-updating-of-tag-wikis-with-content-copied

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256436/how-to-deal-with-plagiarized-content-in-tag-wikis

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255740/wiki-edit-reviewers-are-not-catching-plagiarism

Comment: In many cases it is helpful to have a tag wiki with a single question, it can help to explain why the particular tag was needed.

Comment: @Mogsdad It's basically the same question, sure, but none of the posted answers actually manages to answer it. And we're not supposed to close questions as duplicates of unanswered questions. The system normally blocks it, except that it in this case it can't detect that the question is unanswered.

Comment: @hvd 1. The system blocks duplicating to questions with no _upvoted or accepted_ answers - not quite what you describe. 2. That question is a duplicate. A better answer can be added there.

Comment: @Mogsdad 1. It blocks it in all the cases I described, plus some more that you described that weren't relevant to my point. 2. Vote to close based on the current rules, not what you'd like the rules to be. If the currently implemented rules say that you cannot close as a duplicate of an unanswered question, even if the questions would be word for word identical, that should be a pretty clear indication not to vote to close if the other question doesn't really have an answer. If you don't like those rules, try to get those rules changed, don't just ignore them.

Comment: @hvd What are you arguing about? You admitted yourself the question is the same. The linked question has 3 answers so it is not unanswered. It is your choice to dislike those 3 answers and you can downvote them if you want, but it doesn't hide the fact that it is a duplicate of a question with 3 answers, and, as such, can be close-voted. You can comment on those answers saying why you dislike them also. No-one is circumventing the system here.

Comment: @Tunaki If none of those three answers even remotely attempts to answer the question of how to flag, but this question gets closed as a duplicate anyway, then the system is definitely being circumvented. The only *mention* of flagging in any of those three answers is in Mogsdad's new answer, and only then as a feature request.

Comment: @hvd et al., see the FAQ answer to [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/206345). _Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers._ Whether those answers exist yet or not is not relevant.

Comment: @Mogsdad The fact that that answer says "Unanswered duplicates: [...] If you're convinced that two unanswered questions are duplicates, flag one for moderator attention and explain your reasoning." is a big surprise to me and contradicts what I remember reading on Meta about duplicates. Thanks, I'll accept that unless I can find something that contradicts it.

Comment: @hvd The primary purposes of this question were (1) to get clarity about procedures in response to mass tag wiki plagiarism from a single user, and (2) to report a specific instance of mass plagiarism. (1) is a duplicate and (2) is stale, so I have no problem with closing this question.

Comment: BTW, I found what I remembered reading: [Question says duplicate “already has an answer” but it doesn't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265597) says or at least implies that only a question A can only be closed as a duplicate of an unanswered question B if A and B were asked by the same user. Of course, if @Sneftel is okay with keeping this closed, then no problem with me.