# How to remove "This question may have an answer"?

Tags: support

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696861/how-to-manipulate-figures-while-a-script-is-running-in-python) is flagged as a potential duplicate. Referring to this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not) I read this:

> When your question gets at least 1 vote or flag as a duplicate, the This question may already have an answer here header is added to your question

However, I don't see any flags to my question.

How can I remove the:

> This question may already have an answer here

Comment: You could see *close votes*, but you can't see *flags*.

Comment: You can't see flags. The "Possible duplicate" comment was probably removed but the flag is *still* there: http://i.imgur.com/nV6ObP9.png

Comment: @vaultah, yes it was removed, but the possible duplicate is still there

Comment: @nowox because the user can delete their comment but not retract their flag. If you think, having read the proposed duplicate, that your question *isn't* a dupe, just ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is only visible to the OP (ie you) to give you warning there's either:

- A genuine duplicate that you can insta-close your question against if suitable
- Make an edit to your post to show it's not to hopefully avoid closure (or at least make re-opening smoother)

So, if you're sure it's not a duplicate, just ignore it - no one else can see it anyway.

Note there wasn't a close vote as such on the post - someone flagged it as duplicate (which are different beasts).