# If a question has been flagged as a duplicate but is not really one, then how can an SO user communicate the same (other than comments)?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions, undo

I came across a question from a newbie SO user (but not new to program or the platform) which had been flagged as a duplicate, but it was not really one. It had 2-3 downvotes. It has since been removed. My concern is that it was not really a duplicate of the referenced question. Particularly, the answers in the referenced question would not have answered the given question.

I also found that I was not able to 'answer' the question (likely because it had a negative score).

My understanding is that a few reviewers flagged the question as a duplicate, then a few others downvoted it (without any explanation) and then a bot deleted it.

Is this how it's supposed to be? Is there anything else I could have done?

Edit 1: The OP reverted on one of my queries, so I am aware of the fact that he read it.

Edit 2: On why this is not a duplicate of others:

1. The others only discuss flagging a question as a duplicate. Mine is intended to cover the loss of information resulting in deletion as well, post the deletion.

   The only exception I can see is the OP requesting for deletion especially if an answer was found either in the comments or by the OP themselves. If an answer was present in the comments and such a post was deleted, that would still be loss of information.
2. The post was not deleted since I was able to access it and comment. But answers below indicate that it would need to be deleted for a question to be non-answerable.

Comment: If you couldn't answer the question it was because it was already closed, not because of the downvotes.

Comment: Also, what does "reverted on one of my queries" mean?

Comment: @BilltheLizard There was no 'this question is closed' or similar info block. There should be one right?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not

Comment: @RavindraHV If you couldn't answer the question, then it was closed or it had already been deleted.  Probably closed, by the sounds of it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I had included a query wondering whether the OP was new just to SO or programming or not to which the OP reverted on being new to SO.

Comment: If you happen to still have a link to the question (for instance in your browser history), that would help a lot here, so 10k+ users can see some context, and maybe better explain what happened. (It would also help clarify some of the odd terms you're using.)

Comment: *the OP reverted on being new to SO* - I think you want to say "replied" or "responded" instead of "reverted". Revert means to undo something.

Comment: @Kendra Sorry no. I deleted history. Asking question here was an after thought. Not even under 'all actions' in my profile, which was why I decided to post actually.

Comment: @rene My point is that it did not require an edit. It was short. But as per my interpretation, it was clearly not a duplicate. But since its permanently deleted there is no way I can justify asking the post to be restored. That is why I posted here. Is there any backup anywhere? (Atleast in a private-view of the profile if such a thing exists?)

Comment: @RavindraHV if you don't have a link to the post we can't find it.

Comment: When was it deleted?

Comment: @rene About an 1-2 hours before me posting this question. Thanks for asking !

Comment: Do you have the link to the comment still in your inbox? If so, please click it and post the link here

Comment: @rene Link to comment from OP in inbox http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/57771656. Thanks !

Comment: @rene Assuming you can access the question from the comment, hope the question can be restored if it was not a request from the OP himself.

Comment: here is the [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DesoL.png). The question was dupe hammered by a gold tag badge holder and then deleted by the owner. You could have reached the duplicate voter by @reply-ing to him. Looking at the question I don;'t think it should be un-deleted as I think the duplicate is a good match.

Comment: @RavindraHV Sure looks like a duplicate to me.  I see nothing there to indicate that it's not a duplicate.  Your comment indicating that the OP should roll his own sorting algorithm just because he wants to compare a property of the items instead of the items themselves is borderline irresponsible, as far as I'm concerned.  The answer in the duplicate is the correct answer.

Comment: @rene Thanks for your efforts ! Given that the OP himself asked to delete the question I can only agree. I misunderstood the context then. Thanks again any how!

Comment: @Servy My understanding is that if someone were to copy-paste the implementation in the answer marked duplicate, it would not have resolved the OP's question. Hence my reply in the first place.

Comment: @rene PS: No way to reach to the OP to check if he wanted it deleted. No link to original question or my comment or from inbox. It would be helpful if questions deleted on request by OP simply said so.

Comment: @RavindraHV When you click the link to go to the question, it says _"This question was voluntarily removed by its author."_ OP deleted it himself.

Comment: @rene please visit your reputation tab, man.

Comment: @RavindraHV _"if someone were to copy-paste the implementation in the answer marked duplicate, it would not have resolved the OP's question"_ - that is not at all how duplicates work. That would warrant a new question for everyone who wants to sort on a class property, because they all have a different name... When a question is closed as duplicate, _some_ thinking may still be required.

Comment: @CodeCaster but ...but... I like that green color ... :(

Comment: @Kendra Ok. I missed it. That answers my question. So all I had to do was to look in the inbox. Thanks !

Comment: @CodeCaster Then perhaps it can be closed for being 'similar' than a 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the answers in the duplicate post wouldn't answer the question, then edit the question to explain why those answers wouldn't solve the problem at hand.

You can still post answers to negatively scored questions.  If the question was closed it would prevent answers.  That's the *purpose* of closing questions.

Unless the post was closed for a reason other than being a duplicate, it wouldn't have been deleted automatically.  Either the author, a mod, or 3 users with 10k rep would needed to have voted to close the question to delete it.

Comment: I'm OK with this answer but it would be a duplicate of the question I left as a comment. What is different here is this user is not the OP. Do you still think the question should be edited by another user?

Comment: @rene If it wouldn't be changing the meaning of the question, sure.

Comment: I would edit it only in case I thought there was a problem with it. I think the OP would have wanted to deleted it (not sure why). Which I guess is what happened. But its still loss of information. As per me it should atleast be available to those who participated. For the record if nothing else.

Comment: @RavindraHV Posts aren't hard deleted. The OP or users with 10k+ rep can still access the question, so long as they've got a link to it. So it is still available, just not to you and me (for instance) since we don't have enough rep to access it.

Comment: @Kendra Found link to comment in inbox and posted same above. Thank you !