# I have very few reputation points but disagree with a moderator tagging a question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderation

I don't have enough reputation to comment or to talk to the moderator on the chat, so I don't know what to do about this. A [question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093874/cumulative-bar-chart-in-matlab) was marked as duplicate whereas there are differences that make my answer relevant (in my opinion, at least, the subtleties in the new question are not trivial and justify the differences I posted in my answer).

**Edit:** In my opinion, this question is different from [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not) in the sense that, as a low-reputation user that is *answering* a question, there seems to be no way to "ping" the users that closed the question (I tried the "pinging" by putting the user's name in the comments, but that doesn't seem to work once the question is closed). However, the other question did give me useful information as to what was going on, so I'm glad I've been made aware of it through this post.

What can I do about this? So far, I simply added my justification in the comments...

Comment: Just as an FYI, it was not a moderator who marked the question as a duplicate, just a trusted user. Actual moderators have diamonds next to their name.

Comment: @Jongware OP is not the person who asked the question, they answered it.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  That's from the perspective of the OP, not a third party.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if pinging the user who closed the question works when done from an answer. It works from the question for sure, so I did that to be sure he notices.

Comment: To all, thanks for your comments and help. I see my question is being consistently downvoted, I imagine there is good reason for this (such as protocol that I am not aware of, improper labeling, etc.), I nevertheless think that if I had not asked this "moderation" question as I did I would have had no way to continue helping with my "matlab" answer. I believe I did the "pinging" in the comments, as suggested by @LucasTrzesniewski, and, unless I'm mistaken, I couldn't get much farther from there without posting a new "moderation" question.

Comment: @teppyogi consider accepting my answer to let the meta community know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For completeness sake, I was the one who marked the question with the duplicate that you disagreed with.  I'm not a moderator but I am someone with a gold badge in the question area you answered in (i.e. [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab)) so I have the ability to single-handedly mark duplicate questions in that particular area of interest.

I thought the duplicate that was marked satisfied the OP's problem but upon reading the edits and comments thread made between you and the OP, it actually isn't a duplicate.

As such, I agree with your assessment and I've reopened the question.  Lucas Trzesniewski was kind enough to ping me in the question thread.

---

I hope this is satisfactory!

Comment: Thanks for re-opening the question, I do believe the final solution to that question yielded something new to the community. I've accepted your answer so as to not keep the meta community busy. However, if this same problem should happen to another user, and supposing they landed on this question/answer, how would they go about getting their own problem solved ? Do we have an answer to the more general question of ""what should one do" versus "what should be done about tepp yogi", and if so do you think adding that info to your answer is relevant?