# "Duplicate" partially answers question. - Is it really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

I recently was having with something in Android and I solved it after tough research. So I thought I'd [ask the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161025/what-do-the-parameters-in-getsharedpreferences-do) and give a user a chance to answer the question himself for him to gain reputation.

However, the duplicate answers a part of my question. (I was aware of that before I asked the question; I have seen that question).

1. Should I remove the *"part that is in the duplicate"*? Or should I keep it and ignore the flag?
2. Instead of a question, would it have been more suitable as a comment?
3. Should questions like this really be flagged as a duplicate?

**Note:** I am not here to rant, but to simply get some clarification.

Comment: If the duplicate covers part of it, then edit to focus on the part it *doesn't* cover. If you were aware that was the case already, it's not clear why you didn't do that first time around.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought maybe I'd be helping in explaining the idea for future reader better. Will edit though.

Comment: Also, if you have the answer, why aren't you answering it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe as I said, I *wanted* to give a chance to another user. Obviously now it turns out it wasn't a perfect idea, so I answered it.

Comment: The [canonical question/answer on duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/215552) seems to indicate that you should update your question to make it clear how it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Example of how you can write your question http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106529/41104

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concentrate on the part of your question that isn't answered by the duplicate. If possible leave out the bit that might make think it's a duplicate altogether.

If that's not possible make it clear that the extra information is just that, more information to help people understand the question better and not the problem you want an answer to.