# What should I do if the answers do not fully address all angles of the question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions

I have read here: *["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not)*

But the answer is addressing only when it is not a duplicate.

My point is: I have read a question and went through all its answers, yet none of the answers are satisfying enough (they give you 70% of an answer). The question is old now, and it's rarely visible on the site.

Should I edit the question and bump it up on the feed? That would be an abuse of my edit privilege, and I am not sure if it's really effective.

Should I write another question that would be 99% same words and then say the answer on the duplicate question are not satisfying? That would be very weird and disrespectful to the answerer and its voters.

Should I comment on the answer and ask for more? I actually did that, but the user doesn't seem to be very active on the site and I didn't receive any response.

If I ask you what is OOP, you could say it:

1. It stands for object-oriented programming.
2. Answer1 + it means encapsulation, inheritance.
3. Answer2 + polymorphism, abstraction.
4. Answer3 + code.
5. Answer4 + comparison against functional programming.

To me the existing answers are of type 2. I wanted it at least to be of type 4, possibly 5. **I placed the bounty to draw more attention.**

Comment: This is a general question and needs to be addressed in its generic form. However the question that I think needs a better answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041265/difference-between-generics-and-anyobject-in-swift.

Comment: 30% suggests it will be hard to distinguish between the two. You would have to be *very* explicit in what exactly constitutes the 30% you are missing from the original question.  If you can swing that, you'll be fine.  I wouldn't bet on it, though.

Comment: Does the question really need to have that many angles? Maybe ask multiple (simpler) questions...? Or maybe ask a follow-up question about the detail that is missing from the generic one?

Comment: Question: Does the fact that the answers don't fully satisfy the question indicate that the question is too broad? Or alternatively, that they *do* answer the question but not some tangential aspect that you want, but isn't part of the question/answer?

Comment: If you ask "what is OOP?", first, that's far too broad of a question, and second, how can I possibly understand a comparison against functional programming if I don't even know what it is? A comparison against functional programming would maybe be a *followup* question.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy forget 5, stick to 4

Comment: This sort of mean that the initial question was to broad. It should've been split in smaller questions. If you already have 70% of your answer, then just write a specific question for that 30% only. And show the code you have for the 70% that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation I would be inclined to post a new question, and phrase it to **only ask about the 30%** that you feel was not covered by the existing answers.

---

For example, after having experience using Stack Exchange, I once posted a question on Security.SE:

[Is it possible to have a key for encryption, that cannot be used for decryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7401/is-it-possible-to-have-a-key-for-encryption-that-cannot-be-used-for-decryption)
(answer: yes, it's called asymmetric cryptography)

After finding that this is possible, and reading all the answers there, I realized that I needed a more solid understanding before I could re-iterate this information confidently to my associates.

[Is there a simple example of an Asymmetric encryption/decryption routine?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/is-there-a-simple-example-of-an-asymmetric-encryption-decryption-routine)
(knowing the terms, now looking for proof of concept: code)

Both questions were well accepted. The subsequent question was specifically looking for what may have been considered missing (in my mind) from the original question.

---

Word your new question so that it is clearly asking a **different, more specific question**. If folks think it is a duplicate, then quickly comment on why that is not the case, and consider editing your question.

Make your new question is **concise, clear and specific**. It will probably be well-received.

However, if the new question is an **exact duplicate**, then posting a **bounty** may be your best option.

Answer (score 26):

> Should I edit the question and bump it up on the feed? That would be an abuse of my edit privilege and not sure if it's really effective.

No, you should not edit a post just for the sake of editing it.  You should only be editing a post because you're improving it to make it a better post.

> Should I write another question that would be 99% same words and then say the answer on the duplicate question are not satisfying?

No.  You shouldn't just knowingly post duplicate questions just to try to get attention.

> That would be very weird and disrespectful to the answerer and its voters.

And also anyone looking at active questions.

> Should I comment on the answer and ask for more? I actually did that but the user doesn't seem to be very much active on the site and I didn't receive any response

That's certainly acceptable behavior.  If the answer(s) are missing important information it may also merit a downvote, in addition to a comment explaining what information is missing, but that will depend on context, namely whether you consider the missing information crucial, and whether the information it does have is a useful solution, which is a judgement call.

---

If you simply want to draw attention to the post so that it can get an answer that you would consider acceptable, the appropriate mechanism for that is to put a bounty on the question.

Comment: Since I'm not the OP, will I get notified when the question receives a new answer? Or I have to check manually?

Comment: @Honey I believe users holding a bounty get notifications of answers during the bounty period, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Thanks. how is that your post was edited by Mike? The option to edit is grayed out for me...

Comment: @Honey You don't have 2k rep anymore, and so don't have the privilege to edit posts.

Comment: I did place a bounty on the question. Can you see the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041265/difference-between-generics-and-anyobject-in-swift) **and** the comments on the question. And then let me know if I was right to create a bounty with **deeper** differences? Or I should have just wrote a new question? Because currently I'm being told I should have opened a new question and I'm not sure...