# I placed a bounty on an old question, yet I'm now told to open a new question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, bounty

I already asked [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341744/what-should-i-do-if-the-answers-do-not-fully-address-all-angles-of-the-question) question on meta and was told I should place bounty on a question that needs to bring in more attention and shouldn't ask another question.

So I placed the bounty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041265/difference-between-generics-and-anyobject-in-swift) and added a message to it. I did mention in the question that I'm new to Protocol Oriented Programming. It's at the heart of Swift. Then a person who actually wrote an answer after I placed the bounty and has seen the mention of POP has commented and said I should have opened a new question...

So was I right to place a bounty? Or did I need a much better message (even so if it made the question far deeper)? Or it was just not the right place to ask?

Comment: The bounty message should not be used to convey a completely new aspect to the question. If that's what it does (I can't tell, I know too little about Swift), then yes you should have started a new question. If not, then the bounty was totally ok. I suspect it's the latter but as said I'm not an expert on the topic.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Is it really a new aspect? I mean he's asking about its difference, there are things you can't do with AnyObject. I didn't confine the question. I just said tell me more and more, especially about generics in POP. Swift isn't really OOP, it's POP which I why I actually opened the bounty

Comment: `Is it really a new aspect?` as said, I don't know. If it isn't, the person who directed the comment at you was wrong.

Comment: The real problem is that the question you were trying to ask is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow, regardless of whether you try and "ask" it in the bounty box or whether you post it as a new question. It's OK to be new to the language, but Stack Overflow won't work as a tutorial. You need to narrow down your question into something more specific, and then ask it as a new question.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't asking for a tutorial. I had edits on the accepted answer like 6 months ago. Made a comment on the accepted answer and then answered it myself. I do understand the basic differences in that subject. But I was looking for something more advanced deeper. <-- this is an acceptable reason to open a bounty. There are MANY MANY MANY MANY questions on stackoverflow that simply ask what is the difference of x vs. y. No narrowing down. Yet I actually **did** narrow it down. I said I want it in the context of POP.

Comment: It wasn't an insult regarding your skill or competence level. Your bounty message asked for *"Perhaps the more general/applicable the answer is the better"*, which doesn't seem like a suitable question for Stack Overflow to me. Yes, there are lots of bad questions on Stack Overflow already. This is not an excuse to continue asking them. I don't see how you narrowed anything down. Your comments on the accepted answer seem like clarification questions, and don't have any obvious ties to the bounty message.

Comment: @CodyGray implied in all x vs y questions is a request for its general form. Or is not? Anyways I'll place a new question.

Comment: Which is why we don't do generalized "x vs. y" questions.

Comment: @CodyGray We don't?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438847/difference-between-addchildviewcontroller-and-addsubview | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211317/how-is-abstract-class-different-from-concrete-class | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/whats-the-difference-between-the-atomic-and-nonatomic-attributes | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002819/difference-between-and | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298598/what-is-the-difference-between-git-clone-and-checkout

Comment: @Honey some of those questions are really old (even 2009) and at that time it was more or less allowed I think. Nonetheless, Cody Gray also mentioned this: "Yes, there are lots of bad questions on Stack Overflow already. This is not an excuse to continue asking them."

Comment: @g00glen00b They are all. But the reason they are accepted isn't because they are old. **The language and the time people asked were old**. If there is a **new** language (e.g. Swift) out then there will again be similar questions. See the links below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596785/whats-the-difference-between-a-required-initializer-and-a-designated-initialize | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946690/difference-between-swifts-hash-and-hashvalue | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438368/swift-whats-the-difference-between-metatype-type-and-self

Comment: @g00glen00b https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041265/difference-between-generics-and-anyobject-in-swift | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726170/difference-between-abstract-class-and-interface-in-objective-c | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631137/tuple-vs-dictionary-differences | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809168/anyobject-and-any-in-swift | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002819/difference-between-and

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So here's your bounty quote (emphasis mine)

> Simply put I just want a deeper comparison of the two. Something that would include code. Perhaps the more general/applicable the answer is the better.You can see my comments on the accepted answer. But still if you have more to offer I would appreciate. I'm in the learning phase of generics and POP

And the comment asking you to open a new question

> Huh? You SHOULD open a new question for this because, while the concepts of generics is used in POP, it has got nothing to do with the question asked here -- which is about the difference between dynamic typing and static typing. Icaro's answer answers the question and mine just extends it, with the assumption that just the short explanation wasn't enough. This question has got nothing to do with POP per se and you shouldn't be expecting answers on it. Ask a new question. PS: You didn't "specifically" ask about POP. You just informed that you are learning it.

It sounds like you're asking for something not related to the original question. It's **similar**, but not the **same**, and [yes that can matter a lot](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YpCHzw3WdTo/UzNBI3BzYKI/AAAAAAAAJoY/S34pUkXKhUU/s1600/aaa.png) (I don't know anything about Swift so I can't say for sure that applies here).

In this case, I would say a new question is in order. Read the answer by avismara. Not knowing anything about Swift, it's obvious his answer about this POP thing is cobbled on to his answer from the original question. If I were you, I'd make a new question, link back to this one (helps avoid dupe closure), *quote it where applicable*, and ask specifically about your comments, POP, Swift, etc. If you mod flag the question, they can refund your bounty.

Comment: You the image you linked is my answer :D.  It really wasn't about the bounty, it was more about me figuring out *how to use SO*. Yet awesome to know I *may* get a refund.