# What's best practice for asking a nearly-identical question, but with a critical difference?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418676/triggering-a-jenkins-pipeline-job-from-a-bitbucket-repository) about a specific use-case of Jenkins Pipelines. I'd found a similar question whose advice is out of date, as the answer deals with a now-deprecated function, and linked it because I figured it was relevant. I was less than explicit in my original writing of the post (I accept full blame for it) and didn't go out of my way to state the differences between my question and the question I had linked, not realizing that people wouldn't check and notice that the original question was neither asked nor answered by me and didn't cover my use case due to the software change.

Lesson learned, but the question's now got an "This question may already have an answer here" flag. I believe I have edited the question to more concisely indicate the situation but gotten no reply from the commenter that pointed out my mistake.

**I'd love to know what the right way to handle this is**. Should I have necro-commented on the original answerer's post and asked them if they knew a workaround for webhooks instead of services? Should I keep my question up despite it being in the process of being flagged a duplicate? I'm still learning my way around the site and I'm unsure of the proper procedure in this case.

In response to the comments; I understand that I should have phrased the question better to highlight the differences, and I will do that in the future. My actual question is **is posting a new question the way to go in this scenario, or is there a more accepted alternative?**

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, if not I'll promote this to an answer (if someone else doesn't) but quick answer: State clearly what your difference is. Ex: _"I found this question, but this is asking about Foo, and I need to use Bar instead."_ If the answer to the dupe just doesn't work for you, you're still free to ask a new question, but _explain how the answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: There is no "flag", it is merely a comment from a user that points out that you could do a better job of asking the question.  Well, you already know, it is the basic way to not get any answers.

Comment: Related: [“This question may already have an answer here” - but it does not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not)

Comment: @HansPassant looks like there is a duplicate flag as it is showing up in the vote to close dialog, but doesn't have any votes - so much be a flag,

Comment: Asking new question is fine (if you explain why it is not duplicate), alternative - bounty on old question with detailed explanation (very expensive option for amount of rep you have so far).