# Roll back edited-in commentary about post not being duplicate

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814245/) which is just asking for a standard YAML feature called anchors and aliases. A question asked, and answered, on Stack Overflow before. So I voted to close it as a duplicate, as I don't think we need separate answers for every program happening to use YAML as a configuration file. This is YAML specific, not program specific.

The OP countered with editing the post and adding the following:

> Note to those who have flagged this question as a duplicate: I was instructed by the Concourse team to post this question on here specifically about Concourse configuration. Should configuration ever change from YAML to something else, this post could still act as a reference despite having nothing to do with YAML.

I am of the opinion that that added "note" has nothing to do with programming nor the OPs question and doesn't belong in the post. It actually makes it less readable for future visitors. At most it should be a comment. *Should this edit therefore be rolled-back?* And in general should such edited-in-comments about the (in-)appropriateness of the threat of a question being closed be rolled-back?

I don't agree that being instructed by someone to post something here prevents that from being a duplicate, and I realize that colors my opinion. That is why I looked (and am looking) for guidance here on meta.
Unfortunately [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/252254/7), is unnecessarily unclear at the end especially if elements thereof are taken out of context, or on casual reading. It mentions three points:

---

[image]

---

For anyone familiar with the objective of creating a *quality* Q&A site it is clear that **cohesive** and **well written** are the keywords, those objectives should always have priority. So *And for both*, can only refer to the first two points, not to the third.

The third point, as stated, refers to meta information, a discussion not relevant for future users. Including that in "not in the comments", but in the post itself, automatically makes the post incoherent. That third point should, if at all, be addressed via the other options we have: comments, chat, and posting on meta. It is is not as if there is only one recourse.

---

¹<sub>Or edited out in case other, valuable changes were made.</sub>

Comment: I believe it should be rolled back. It doesn't explain why that question is different from the target. All it does is to lay out a hypothetical scenario which has nothing to do with the current state of the question.

Comment: Let’s say that Concourse changes their configuration language. If the question was updated to reflect the new configuration, it would be a chameleon question, which is something we **do not** encourage here, because all of the answers would become invalid.

Comment: @JF I agree, the question should stay there as-is for people working with older versions. And that is independent of whether the Q is marked as duplicate with or without an answer of its own.

Comment: @Anthon I have clarify the meta answer you quoted.  "Both" did not reference the 3 points but something else entirely, but probably was nor the best choice of phrasing given the confusion.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for piping in. Do you agree that the edit made by the OP, that I refer to, is not an improvement on the clarity nor *explains* why it is not a duplicate. And as such should not be been made as an edit to the post, but e.g as a comment?

Comment: @Anthon I see the point TinyGiant is making.  It is an attempt to explain why it isn't a duplicate.  But at the same time, I think it is terrible attempt to explain why it isn't a duplicate.  It could have been written a lot better, less like a "I was told to post this by..." and more like the actual reason ("Concourse my choose to change the implementation from YAML in the future"), although I don't think it would have changed the fact that it is a duplicate as it stands today.

Answer (score 11):

You summarized it yourself very clearly, in my opinion, in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814245#comment76664082_44814245) you left:

> Whether someone instructed you to post this question or not has **nothing** to with this being able to be a duplicate or not. I am not sure why you made that edit, all that stuff after "note to" has nothing to do with your problem nor with programming. As such that edit is inappropriate, distracts from your question and degrades it. Even assuming this question gets closed as duplicate it doesn't go away, so people can still find it if they look for [concourse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concourse). It is not necessary to have a separate *answer* about anchors for every program that happens to use YAML for their config.

I took the liberty to roll back that edit (and in the process, tried to clarify the question).

In short, a question that is [a duplicate acts as a signpost towards a canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). The question can still be useful for, in this case, concourse users. It's just that the answer need not be duplicated.

Answer (score 5):

### I agree with the duplicate closure, but disagree with the rollback.

When people ask how to dispute a duplicate closure, we tell them to edit their question for a few reasons, one of those being to [**explain why their question isn't a duplicate**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252254/4639281). That is exactly what this person did. They edited their question to explain why they believe their question is not a duplicate of the target. That said, their explanation *is* misguided, but that does not mean that they should be prevented from using their recommended recourse against duplicate closure.

Comment: So you essentially you say: leave that material about duplicate or not in the post for others to wade through for future readers. I think that "recommendation" leads to post that should be down voted as unclear because they contain (programming-)question irrelevant material. Why would I care as future visitor with the same Q as the OP, that the OP disagreed at some point in time with a third person's vote for closing or not (independent of whether the post was actually closed or not).

Comment: I'm stating that the person is following the policy as defined by the community. If you disagree with that policy you should start a new discussion about changing it. Regardless of whether you or I individually believe the policy to be incorrect, they did what we told them to do, then we threw that back in their face, leaving the asker in an advanced state of confusion and frustration.

Comment: The answer you linked to states "And please don't stuff "EDIT:" at the bottom or top of the post. Just rewrite your question to clarify and make the whole post as cohesive and well written as possible."  That advice was not followed: 1) I consider "Note to" and "Update" to be similar to "EDIT:") and 2) the post was no longer as cohesive and well written as possible. The OP at no point tried to improve the post to make any possible distinction more clear.

Comment: Nice out of context quote there bud. That is with regards to _the words_ "note" and "edit". Here's what came directly before that quote: _"**Explain why the question isn't a duplicate.** It is possible the question is similar and a good explanation and help clarify the problem. It is also possible you tried that solution and it didn't work. If so, then explain what you tried and why it didn't work. And for both, **do not do this in comments, but edit the question.**"_

Comment: You didn't comment on **"no longer as cohesive and well written as possible"**? The OP in my opinion, completely ignored that. YMMV.

Comment: Thats your opinion. I find it perfectly cohesive as is. It doesnt bother me in the slightest. You're making a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: [I see what you did there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/252254/8). Unfortunately you don't go about changing community consensus by just editing it to fit your every whim and desire. As I said, if you would like to change the policy, start a new discussion on meta to that effect.

Comment: Maybe you should re-read my question. I already asked for how to handle defacing this stuff in general, starting that discussion here and now. [That posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/252254/7) uses "both" although there are three points mentioned above it. As your confusion (quoting "both" without comment) shows, it is not clear to the casual reader, unfamiliar with the primary goal of having a quality Q&A site, that the third point is not included in that "do not do this in comments", as it automatically contradicts the coherency mentioned later. My edit clarified that.

Comment: @Anthon and '@TinyGiant sorry for keeping changing this comment (hard to remember why I wrote 3 years ago).  "Both" referred whether your question was closed or was still open and just had a few dup-votes or flags.  Since it was misinterpretted, I tried to address that.

Comment: A dupe disambiguation edit must still conform to all normal editing rules, and if it turns out that an edit, even by the OP, makes the post worse, rolling back is the thing to do. The fact that *an attempt was made* by the OP to disambiguate doesn't mean the attempt is actually worth keeping as-is, or means anything.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Its a duplicate question which means that any unregistered users who find this link in a search will be automatically redirected to the target. That means that this is unlikely to be seen by more than a few people in the next few years. This is causing literally no harm whatsoever, and fighting against it _is_ causing harm in that it creates an issue where there was none previously. There are so many more important problems to deal with than this.

Comment: @TinyGiant: So, say, vandalism would be OK if it's on a dupe or deleted post that most people won't see?

Comment: A poor duplicate disambiguation is the equivalent of vandalism? Again with the mountain and the molehill. This is a misguided duplicate disambiguation message on a low quality dupe question. The new shade of green on the profile page is more important than bickering over this.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I'm trying to understand your reasoning for *utterly* ignoring lousy edits to dupes on principle. If you advised someone to spend their time better, well, OK. But saying that the rollback flat-out shouldn't have been made... well, that's the old "too minor" rejection reason again. And mind you, you said it was causing "literally no harm whatsoever". If a lousy dupe explanation causes no harm *because* so few people see it, what's so horrible about a vandalized deleted post when even fewer will see that?

Comment: it's a dupe disambiguation edit which _is_ allowed. It's a poor one, but one nonetheless. The fact that it will neber be seen just adds to the fact that this is a pointless argument. @NathanTuggy

Comment: @TinyGiant: So a dupe disambiguation edit that throws in a bunch of irrelevant comments and personal insults would be … left that way because it doesn't matter? Or what? "Dupe disambiguation edit" **is not a free pass**. It's *one possible valid purpose*, just like "edit to add MCVE" is, but in all other ways …*still gotta follow the normal rules*. I mean, OK, again, priorities — you can say "technically rollback is the correct action but no one cares" and I would agree, but that's emphatically not what you are saying at all.

Comment: @TinyGiant Although I believe that the note does not add to the question, I appreciate your reasoning. Just to be transparent: I (tried to) clarify the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814245/) while I was removing the note, this got undone by your rollback. I just edited that back in, and formatted the note to at least not distract so much from the actual question. Hope you agree with that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What part of the message is rude? It looks like it follows the normal rules to me, its just wrong. I actually do not think the rollback was correct. A dupe disambiguation edit is not a free pass to be rude or write obscenities, but it doesn't have to be correct in order to be allowed as a dupe disambiguation edit either.

Comment: @Justastudent I can agree with that.