# I really don't know why this question is deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I answer many questions and sometimes they are deleted because they are duplicates! It is ok! But this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44703028/5558072):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702893/convert-an-array-of-char-into-several-string

It is clear that it is not duplicate, in my solution I based on two problems. The person who marked it as duplicate looked at my answer and marked it as a duplicate of those two different problems?

Is that legal?

What should I do in this case?

[For people with less than 10K rep](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628161554/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702893/convert-an-array-of-char-into-several-string)

---

Comment: *"This hurt me a lot, and lead me to do bad actions"* wut

Comment: yes @KevinB this happen to me many times so it make me angry, i don't post because it is the first time no, but because it is a good question and a good answer

Comment: It's also worth noting that, in addition to being a duplicate, the question doesn't even ask an (unanswered) question.  The question *contains an answer* that the OP had right from the start, and it worked.  There was no problem to be solved from the start.

Comment: `"What should i do in this case?"` -- vote to close questions that look to be common duplicates rather than answer them.

Comment: you can check @yivi

Comment: @yivi: [Archive.org's most recent archive of the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628161554/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702893/convert-an-array-of-char-into-several-string)  This bookmarklet will open Archive.org's calendar of archives for the page you are currently viewing: `javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/web/*/'+location.href))`

Comment: If it was me, I'd put both the link to Archive.org's archive and a link to the 10k+ screenshot, but not have the screenshot display inline (i.e. markdown that is `[]` not `![]`), but I tend to over-supply information.

Comment: The actual criteria for a question, Q, being a duplicate is that the *answer(s)* on the dup-target provide the information to answer Q. Basically, if the answer(s) on the dup-target could be copy-&-pasted to the duplicate to answer Q (with, perhaps, minor changes), then Q is a duplicate. One of the nice things about gold-badges being able to add multiple dup-targets is that **many** questions are "unique" because the OP has conflated two+ separate questions/problems. Multiple dup-targets allows fully covering those situations, rather than having new answers for "combo" questions.

Answer (score 21):

Is it legal for someone to look at an answer, use that to determine that the question is actually a duplicate of two other questions, and close the question as a duplicate of those questions that show how to answer it?  Yes, it sure is.  Why *wouldn't* we want a question to be closed as a duplicate of questions that show how to answer it, when those other questions already exist?

That it hurts you to have your answer answering a duplicate question removed, should be a sign to you that you shouldn't be answering common duplicates.  Instead spend your time and effort answering questions that aren't already answered (and that are otherwise high quality questions) and you won't have that problem.

Comment: ok what is the solution now? should i shut my face and accept it like this?

Comment: @YCF_L Don't answer common duplicates, or other low quality questions that meet closure criteria.  Spend your time answering quality questions whose answers will actually be of value.  I said as much in my answer.

Comment: i really don't see this duplicate questions and this is not the first time, it happen to me many times, i know the reason but i will hide it, if you check my profile you will see that my events is decrease day by day just because this actions, beside this is not low quality question whatever i really start to hating this events

Comment: @YCF_L You say the question isn't a duplicate, and then say it's wrong of them to close the question as a duplicate of questions that provide the same answer you provided.   That is a contradiction.  If you decide that you'd rather not participate at all, than participate by providing valuable content, and that you're only willing to participate in the site by providing content that's *not* useful, then that's up to you.  It is your decision to make after all.

Comment: ok don't look at my answer there are others answers and also good answers is that also legal

Comment: Yes, it's legal for anyone with the privilege to downvote to downvote any post, as long as they're not targeting the poster specifically

Comment: @YCF_L if you believe the question is not duplicate there is well defined process to improve and clarify the post (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not). You can make edit adding "I tried {approaches} from {links to duplicates} but id did not work for my case because {some reasons}" (edit would be marginally ok if there is no answers but  in current state it would invalidate answers in addition to putting words in OPs mouth).