# Close question as duplicate even when the duplicate did not solve OP issue

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, dupehammer

I usually run into questions that is a duplicate of another question where OPS linked the duplicate question in that question but clearly mentioned in the question that none of the answers from the duplicate worked for them.

To me, OP linked the duplicate and it shows that they did their homework and research it. I usually keep these questions open and don't close them since the duplicate did not solve their issue. I close them if there is a mistake in the question that resulted to the problem not being solved.

Today, the-same thing happened and I left the question open but few hours later, I saw this comment under the question from a high rep user:

[image]

Now, I feel like I've been doing it all wrong.

Should I close questions that are duplicates even if the presumed duplicate did not actually solve the problem for the OP?

I personally don't think that closing them will help anyone but it's good to hear from people on this.

---

**EDIT**:

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not).

The linked question you have is about 2 different questions. This question is asking about 2 exact questions with the first one not solving the issue.

Comment: depends. did it not solve the ops problem because the op doesn't understand their problem? or was it simply a different problem. In the former case it's likely still a dupe, the op just needs help implementing it.

Comment: Nope. Did not solve the problem because it did not solve it. Not OP's fault. It's really a complicated issue. I didn't want to link it but I think I should for better understanding. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756244/scripts-stay-miscellanous-files).

Comment: in that case, i'd say yea, it's still a duplicate, and the other question simply doesn't have all the answers yet. Might be worth keeping this question open until an answer is found, then requesting a merge to move the new answer over.

Comment: That actually sounds like a great idea. Although, that means I should be closing future similar questions or just leave them open, get an answer and then flag for a mod to merger it?

Comment: just in very special circumstances. such as this one. The reason i'd leave the new one open temporarily is because the newer question could attract new answers, and/or improvements to existing answers, where as if the question is simply closed as a dupe immediately it's highly unlikely anyone will spend the time to figure out why the existing answers don't fix this scenario.

Comment: I wouldn't apply this to programming questions, only IDE questions. most cases involving programming are just cases of the OP not understanding, where as problems with editors could be far more involved.

Comment: Ok. Just to let you know that the platform I mostly answer questions on usually has this kind of problem (even programming). Sometimes, the duplicate does not help at-all and the issue is totally another different stuff.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If the question is the same than it's a duplicate. No matter if the answer solved the problem. If OP wants another answer they can place a bounty on the original one and explain why it needs another answer. In every other case the solutions to the problem would be scattered over multiple questions.

Comment: @gnat Not a duplicate. The linked question you have is about 2 different questions. This question is asking about 2 exact questions with the first one not solving the issue.

Comment: @BDL Maybe if they have 75 rep, what about the majority of other users? guess they're just SOL.

Comment: Point 3 in the answer from the dupe still applies: _"3. Explain why the question isn't a duplicate."_ If the question is an exact duplicate, but the answer doesn't answer your scenario, explain why it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to your question is in the closed message box for all duplicate posts

[image: Duplicate close message box]

To quote the relevant portion:

> If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

So, yes, if someone has a problem and the existing answers do not solve your problem, the site is actually encouraging the users to ask a new question.

---

However, just stating "I tried everything there and nothing works" is a waste of text.  That sentence does not constitute any kind of research effort, and without more explanation, the question should be closed as "Unclear what you are asking" if you don't close it as a duplicate.

Why is it unclear?  It is unclear because no one can answer the question in that state.  You have a (presumably) well answered duplicate with 1 or more potential solutions.  If the user actually tried those solutions, they should be able to provide some sort of explanation as to what or why the linked duplicate isn't working.

- Are they getting an error messages
- Is there an MCVE showing how they tried to apply the solution(s) and some explanation as to what is working and what isn't?
- Are there any other details that may make the askers situation different than the linked duplicate

Without any above, the any potential answerer is just left guessing as to why the solutions in the duplicate don't work, hence the fact that question is "unclear".

In the end, finding a duplicate and trying the solutions is only a small part of the users research effort.  They need to take the time to do the additional research as to why the solution they tried isn't working (which includes other solutions found both on SO and other sites on the internet).  And it is their responsibility to make sure the potential answerers have enough info to answer.