# Why was my question marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52037383/6605349) of mine was unilaterally marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3155436/6605349) by a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) gold badge holder almost immediately after I asked it. However, all of the answers in the question that it was marked a duplicate of involved using a metaclass to apply magic methods to the class itself, which I specifically said didn't work in my case (using metaclasses would involve inheriting from `type` and `Exception`, which raises a TypeError).

I had already read that question and its answers before I asked, and I had made a point of mentioning how it didn't work.

Edit: Someone suggested that this is a possible duplicate of ["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/6605349) - however, that question is asking why there is a *possible* duplicate header; I am asking why my question was completely marked as a duplicate.

Why was my question marked as a duplicate?

Comment: It was closed by a single user, who has a gold badge in the Python tag. Gold tag badge holders can single-handedly close as duplicates.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I am aware of that; I am mostly bringing this up because I don't believe that the question was a duplicate, but am willing to accept reasoning as to why it in fact was (if it really is a duplicate and should remain such).

Comment: I have notified the gold badged user of this meta. They expressed appreciation. With a little luck there will be more insight soon.

Comment: If you do not believe it is a duplicate, the proper course of action would be to edit your original question and explain there why it is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the user who marked the question as duplicate.

I marked your question as duplicate of [__getattr__ for static/class variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155436/getattr-for-static-class-variables-in-python) because both questions want to achieve the same thing - dynamic attributes on a class. All answers in that question will show you how to solve your problem, so it is a duplicate.

You say that those answers *don't* solve your problem:

> However, all of the answers in the question that it was marked a duplicate of involved using a metaclass to apply magic methods to the class itself, which I specifically said didn't work in my case (using metaclasses would involve inheriting from type and Exception, which raises a TypeError).

But the reason for this is very simple: It's not that the answers don't work, it's that you aren't using the metaclass correctly. If you change your class definition from `class APIError(Exception, meta):` to `class APIError(Exception, metaclass=meta):`, the `TypeError` will go away.

I suppose I should've left a comment on your question to tell you about this mistake, but I thought you'd end up with correct code anyway if you apply the answers from the duplicate to your problem. That was an oversight on my part. I will leave a comment explaining how to use the metaclass correctly after I finish writing this meta post.

---

So, to summarize: The answers in the duplicate solve your problem, as long as you apply them correctly.

---

(P.S.: In the future, please contact the gold badge user who closed your question directly before making a meta post. Just leave a comment with a ping to `@Aran-Fey` under your question and I'll respond as soon as I'm able. It's far more efficient than posting a meta question.)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification! I didn't realize I was applying that question's methods wrong.