# High-rep user removing OP text from question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, rollback-wars

I recently stumbled upon a question that was marked as duplicate, followed by the OP editing the question trying to explain why they think the question is not a duplicate. However the user who hammer-closed the question as duplicate keeps removing that explanation, even after I tried to explain why the explanation should not be removed.

IMO, it's the OP's right to try and explain why they think the question is not a duplicate. To be honest, I'm not an expert on the domain of the question, and I'm not questioning the closing reason, nor the explanation the OP added. What I don't agree with is that high-rep user keep removing that explanation.

As I don't want to get sucked into a rollback-war, what are my other options? I already added a commend nicely saying why I think the OP's text should be kept, but in vain.

Note that I don't want to link the question here, unless necessary.

P.S. The question has reopen votes, there's were I stumbled upon it.

**Edit** Since discussing theoretical issues might not be the best approach, I'm adding a link to the question: [Ansible contructing variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592315/ansible-contructing-variable-name). The OP's explanation might not be good, but it's their contents, it's not rude, it's not offensive, it's related to the question. It should've been kept, IMO.

**Edit 2** I'm not trying to debate about the contents of the question, and if it should be closed or not, my only concern was related to the text the OP added after the question was closed, that got removed. IMO, censorship doesn't deserve a place on SO.

Comment: Your only option is to flag for moderator attention, explain the situation, and let a mod handle it.

Comment: @yivi I thought of that, however mods have a lot on their plate, didn't want to bother them for something this simple :)

Comment: Maybe I'll gave rollback another go, and after that reach to moderators, if things don't change.

Comment: There are no other options. If you wanted to discuss the specific question, the community could help you. Without that, only a mod can get all the information to handle it appropriately.

Comment: @Cristik From your description, it _sounds like_ (can't confirm without seeing the actual instance) one user borderline vandalizing a post... Definitely a place for mods. Whatever you do, _do not_ engage in the war. One rollback, then flag, that's the general guideline.

Comment: Mind, that I will revert your rollback because it doesn't belong to the question on meta. Regarding this question: you did not link to the question, you did not add the contents of the edit you reverted, you instead add drama and some fake information quote "*even after I tried to explain why the explanation should not be removed*". How do you think is it answerable?

Comment: @Cristik I won't link the post either, but I completely agree with removing the text.  It adds nothing to the question, and has no place being there.  The question was a valid duplicate.  The only edit to change that should be editing the content of the question, not adding a disclaimer.  I also see no comment about leaving his explanation, so either it was removed or it does not exist.

Comment: @techraf I added a comment saying you why the edit should be kept. I deleted that comment after a couple of minutes as I'm pretty sure you got it via the notifications system.

Comment: How can I get a comment which you deleted?

Comment: @techraf you have enough rep here, to understand what I meant.

Comment: @davidism It does say a little more than "no it's not", it _attempts_ to explain why not. (Poorly, but it looks like the OP of that question might not have a full mastery of English.)

Comment: No, I don't understand what you mean. If you write a comment and delete it, I have no way of seeing it.

Comment: I added a link to the question. IMO, the OP's text should've been kept.

Comment: Everyone can see what that question is about and no further explanation from OP is required. And also by following the link to the duplicate everyone can see that the answer to the question is "Fix the indentation of the with_ declaration". In other words "remove two spaces". And I'm sure OP would also see that. I don't see a reason for your intervention here.

Comment: @techraf when someone posts a comment, you get a notification, my mistake was to delete that comment as I was sure you've seen it, especially considering you're active at this hour. Might've been a mistake to delete it, won't make that mistake in the future :)

Comment: "*as I was sure you've seen it, especially considering you're active at this hour*" -- No, I was walking my dog while you reverted the edit.

Comment: @techraf I'm not debating the question contents at all, I'm discussing about the added text only.

Comment: This is what's confusing me.  If you don't think there is anything unclear about the question contents, and you agree with the duplicate, why should the question have it's title edited to "This not a duplicate"?  I don't understand how that is helpful for someone else who stumbles across the same issue.  If I had that problem I would *hope* that someone else had the issue so I could easily find an answer to it.

Comment: @user3483203 If you take a look at the revision history, you'll notice that right after I rolled back the removal, I updated the title and removed that part. Saying that a question is not a duplicate is something that just adds noise to the title.

Comment: The question you are discussing is a "typo" question which should be closed and deleted from SO. Because **I did not want to engage 4 other people** I decided to close it and because similar questions were asked in the past I closed it as a duplicate of one and explained to the OP what they should do.　I removed OP's edit **to avoid engaging more people** in reopening and closing the question again.　I honestly do not understand your need to engage whole community here. I hope you will get an answer to this meta question from someone else, because I do not understand it.

Comment: @techraf having instant edit capabilities doesn't mean you can play with others questions as you like. As I said before, It's OP's right to add any information to the question, as long as it's related to the topic, and it follows the code on conduct.

Comment: At least this is how I see things here on SO.

Comment: @techraf again, I'm not questioning the question itself, only the text the OP added after the question was closed.

Comment: Why are you asking me, why the question has a reopen vote? Ask the user who voted to reopen https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21010817

Comment: @techraf I was not asking  you :) That was just something I noticed. This is how I stumbled upon the question, by walking through the reopen queue.

Comment: If "*you were not asking me*", then [why did you explicitly add my username to your now deleted comment?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8w1Y.png)

Comment: @techraf because the discussion continued between us  two. The question was not necessarily indented for you. It was mostly a rhetorical one, no need for you to answer it.

Comment: @techraf however I feel we're diverging from the goal of the question. I say the edit should've been kept because the user tries to explain why the question is not a duplicate. If it's a good explanation or not, that's to debate. But you shouldn't have remove it. The question was already in the reopen queue, your rollback helped no-one. Thus, I'm reverting it once more.

Comment: So that you put it back into reopen queue and engage more users. I think you should think about your conduct.

Comment: If the edit doesn't clarify that it isn't a dupe, or does it incorrectly... What's the value in such an edit? I get you want to keep as much of the original poster's content as you can, but if the content adds only noise to the question, it should be removed. No? (Btw your question here says you won't engage in rollback wars... That's good. Don't start now :/)

Comment: @techraf a question has only once chance to be reopened.

Comment: @Patrice is the content in discussion noise? To me, it feels legitimate text

Comment: @Patrice I won't rollback the third time, I promise :)

Comment: @Cristik if it incorrectly makes the point it's trying to make (which it seems it does, since you say the duplicate is likely correct) what value does it have? I see none. Therefore IMHO it's noise

Comment: Hopefully by now a diamond moderator has been alerted about the rollback war going on. Can we just wait for the moderator to step in here please? Take the rest of this to chat if you must.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I wouldn't call a 2-by-2 rollback a war. But I could be wrong :)

Comment: @Patrice my question is why do we apply censorship here on SO? We've just celebrated 10 years, why are we deleting legitimate content just because we don't agree with it?

Comment: @Cristik we've ALWAYS moderated and removed content. Over those 10 years. Just like we remove 'hello' and 'thanks'. It's not censorship. It's keeping a high signal-to-noise ratio. If the edit isn't making the dupe a non dupe, what purpose does it have?

Comment: @Patrice why should we reject attempts in explaining why the question is not a duplicate? This is not like keeping the question closed as a duplicate, but actually removing contents from the question.

Comment: @Patrice do we do the same with incomplete questions? We start removing contents because they're anyway incomplete?

Comment: @Patrice if the question is still a duplicate after the added contents, then let's let the community decide this, not a single user

Comment: @Cristik incomplete questions are eventually deleted .. so..... Yes? And I don't see this as an attempt at rejecting anything. If the question was truly not a dupe, I would hope techraf would instead reverse their close vote and not simply rollback. If the question is still a dupe, then yes the edit (again, in my eyes) is noise. People can say 'I think my question isn't a dupe'. We're not talking about removing that chance. We're talking about removing the text, if it's deemed like it's not useful.

Comment: @Patrice please read the text, it's not just "this is not a duplicate" (excepting the title edit)

Comment: (whether the edit was rollbacked or not, the question has been sent to the reopen queue so the community still will be able to decide this. I do get your point about the single point of failure and I can stand behind that a bit. Not sure it's what happened here, but it definitely could lead to incorrect moderation)

Comment: I did read the text. I don't think it makes the question a non-dupe.

Comment: @Patrice and who is you or me to disallow users edit their questions? Why should we rollback users that have problems formulating edits in english?

Comment: Man you go EVERYWHERE with this. First it was censorship, now it's about English. I never talked about **any** of these. I always go back to 'the edit doesn't help de-dupe the question. It's noise'. The rest doesn't and shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Patrice the only goal of this meta question was to say that the edit should be allowed. No more than this. I'm not questioning the duplication. But the OP should be allowed to edit the question. Rolling back the edit doesn't seem good to me

Comment: @Patrice I'm not deviating from censorship, which I feel this is what happened to the question being discussed.

Comment: @Patrice what I'm failing to understand here is why the edit was removed. That edit helped no-one, since the question was already on the reopen queue. And the edit was not a harmful one. So why remove it? WHY? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: @techraf: "*Because I did not want to engage 4 other people I decided to close it and because similar questions were asked in the past I closed it as a duplicate of one and explained to the OP what they should do.*" Do not do that. Your dupe-hammering powers were *not* given to you to close typo-questions. They were given to you to close *duplicate* questions. Using a close reason improperly is precisely *why* we don't trust users to single-vote close questions for other reasons.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is a duplicate question. To answer it, I would have to write "Fix the indentation". I (and many others) already did that under multitude of questions within this tag. The duplicate target I have chosen for this question was the most appropriate, because it related to the same `with_`-loop declaration that this question had failed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be fair this should have been closed as a typo instead, then no edits to the question would have been necessary.

This is because the duplicate close banner **actually encourages the asker to edit the question to explain**<sup>#</sup> why the question isn't a duplicate of the linked question. One could have just pointed out in the comments that the typo/code formatting was the issue.

Also, please do not engage in a rollback war (multiple rollbacks performed on the same post in succession). You can use the comments to clarify and resolve the situation first, or flag for moderator attention if a consensus cannot be reached.

---

<sup>#</sup> The duplicate banner close text the *asker* sees is:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

This is slightly different from what everyone else sees, and was probably implemented in 2013 described in this [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/).

Comment: What banner are you talking about? While I am not sure what exactly the OP of a duplicate-closed questions sees, but what everyone else does is "*This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.*"　I don't get how you can describe it as "encouraging the user to edit the question and explain", so maybe you meant some other. Would you mind including it in your answer?

Comment: Close. The exact text is: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, **please edit this question to explain how it is different** or ask a new question."

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to communicate by writing the noun "*close*". [The message looks exactly this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKRiM.png). Would you mind elaborating? Is the message different depending on the user?

Comment: @techraf I have a question that got marked as duplicate, here's a screenshot of how the banner looks like to me: https://i.imgur.com/yQq5i5N.png. It's exactly as the others say.

Comment: Not sure if admins just changed the dupe text, because I swear I copied the text from a duped question in my previous comment, but here's an example in the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions (*screenshot before this is changed too(?) https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU3Ji.png*) This same close text was also described in the blog here https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/

Comment: Perhaps the "edit" wording only displays under certain conditions now. This is all too confusing.

Comment: @SamuelLiew the banner looks different for the OP vs. rest of the users. For my question I see exactly the message you were referring to, for other questions I see the one without the edit part (likely because I should be the one that clarifies the duplication stuff)

Comment: Even aside from the banner text, "explain how your question isn't a duplicate" is exactly the advice given on meta to every user wanting to dispute duplicate closure: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not