# What if none of the answers in a potential duplicate question work?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

**TLDR:**

In general, if all the answers are not working, should the question asker comment on it or ask a new question?

What should we do if they comment on it and there isn't any response?

---

I asked a question, then I re-framed it after some comments, and I found that it is a dupe for another one ([Sublime Text 3 snippet not working in plain text file with no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793613)).

But the answer in the original does not work.
(It is a configuration file. I changed it, but there wasn't any effect.)

If this situation arises: Should I comment on the original and close my question as duplicate?

In general, if all the answers are not working, should the question asker comment on it or ask a new question?

If they comment on it, is it less likely attract the users than a new question?

What should we do if they comment on it and there isn't any response?

Comment: What do you mean, "does not work"?  How does it not work?  Is the code incomplete?  Does it not fit your specific scenario?  Readers need far more to go off of to understand why there might be a difference.

Comment: Comment and inform the users *what* doesn't work. Be as specific as possible. As it currently stands, your comment: '*This doesn't work for me*' is pretty useless, provide some details. If you feel you can justify why you need another question, feel free to make one.

Comment: It depends on why it is not working. If your problem has some slightly other constraints that prevent these answers from working, then keep your question.

Comment: @fbueckert I tried the solution but it not working.

Comment: Okay, so that's a step.  We need more than, "not working".  Does it not compile? Is something missing? Is your scenario different enough that the code doesn't match? Or maybe it compiles, and doesn't do anything?  There needs to be some digging on your end to be able to tell us more than just, "it's not working".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the OP may be more concerned about the general rule for this kind of situation than this specific instance. Or are you concerned about this specific example?

Comment: @yivi General if they comment on it and there is no response

Comment: For the most part, your answer is going to exist [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/).  The main issue you're running into here is that you're unable to define the difference between your question and the duplicate.  Without that, your new question can't help anyone else (or curators) figure out how they're different.  Until you are able to articulate how your question differs, you shouldn't ask a new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on my comments:

The onus of a question not being a duplicate is on the asker; they need to be able to clearly differentiate between their question and the duplicate.  We *can't* help if we don't see a difference between them.  Not won't, but really *can't*.  This requires the asker to be able to be skilled enough to check the duplicate, and articulate *why* the question is different, or why the existing answers don't help.

"It doesn't work" is what we usually get, and isn't enough to be able to help them, let alone future readers.  Questions are supposed to be able to help more than just the asker.  If the asker themselves can't make readers aware of how the question is different...how is anyone else supposed to?  We can't play guessing games, or pull the details out of the asker bit by bit.  This is information that *must* be provided so that we can actually help them.

In the event that you run into a question where it's the same problem, but the answers don't help, you have a good start to your research.  You know it's been asked, but the answers don't solve your issue.  At this point, you shouldn't ask another question.  You don't have enough information yet.  What you should do, though, is start digging.  Why don't the answers work?  Is the scenario different? Have you tried the answers?  What did they do?  What results did they have?

What this boils down to is essentially investing effort into solving your problem.  Quite often, doing so obviates the need to ask a question in the first place.  In the event that you've tried the answers, and you've managed to isolate where the difference is in them, and still can't solve yours, *that* is when you ask a new question.  You include the research you've done, linking to the other questions you found, and tell us why they and their answers didn't work.  That makes the question different, and shows us you put effort into it yourself.

Commenting, in general, isn't meant to ask for more help from answerers.  That goes doubly for, "I tried this and it didn't work."  Like I said, that doesn't help anyone.  If the problem is close enough that it would be a minor change to the answer and wouldn't invalidate the existing problem, you *might* have a case, but that's generally a very narrow exception.  You're far better off digging on your own and asking your own question once you determine the difference between yours and theirs.