# Can we get this question Unmarked as Duplicate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicate-questions

**UPDATE: Why this is not a duplicate of the indicated duplicate:**

Because the indicated duplicate is about how the Original Poster can fix the issue. In this case, we have a question that was posted quite a long time ago and the original poster was a new user who never bothered to address the issue. The question showed up from a Google search I performed. I myself need an answer to the question and the question never got answered, nor is it a duplicate.

My understanding is that the correct way to get a question unmarked as duplicate is to bring it up in Meta. Is that right?  If yes, here is a question in question:

[Mono C# enable https with httplistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550631/mono-c-sharp-enable-https-with-httplistener)

The supposed duplicate question has nothing to do with Mono. And yes, there seems to have been (or still is) an issue with SSL with Mono and httpListener so this question is pertinent to other users. I have yet to find out if the issue was ever resolved. I found this SO question through Google because I was searching for information on the same problem.

Comment: Ok. So this appears to be an issue in the way Stackoverflow functions. That other question says the only way to fix a duplicate is for the original poster to make a request. That is a big problem. The original OP is off the grid, and other users can clearly see that the question is not a duplicate.  Is there no way for other users to get someone else's question fixed?

Comment: @JamesHoux the question is written in first person. I don't see anything there that says only the OP can request removal of the duplicate. It's certainly not necessary, they're just the most likely person to ask.

Comment: @Catija Well that is very confusing.  Because I tried to validate the answers by following their instructions.  I don't see the option to Reopen the question when I look at it. The alternative answer is SPECIFIC to the OP and it actually says in the comments that ONLY THE OP SEES IT.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm talking about the suggested duplicate here on MSO. You stated: "That other question says the only way to fix a duplicate is for the original poster to make a request."  That's incorrect. Anyone can make such a request. The question is from the PoV of the asker, so I can see why you might think that, but it's not the case.

Comment: Well I am having a great deal of trouble finding that option in the UI.  One of the answers on the duplicate MSO question linked above says that there is a Reopen link next to Edit.  I only have Share and Edit showing on my end.

Comment: The question you're trying to get reopened has already been reopened... that's why your question here is tagged status-completed.

Comment: @Catija Thank you.  I see that now. However the question still stands. Look at this dup question for example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array

There is no Reopen option or anything of that sort anywhere on the UI unless you are the OP.  At least thats what it looks like on my screen.

Comment: @JamesHoux: The top-voted answer says: "If you want your question reopened, edit it and explain why it is not a duplicate.". This can be done by anyone. If you have > 10k, you can also vote to reopen. Admitingly, the better duplicate for the meta question is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not-or-what-ca)

Comment: So the process of reopening a question *absolutely requires* editing the question? Huh.  That seems fairly non-intuitive to me.  I guess from my perspective the question was completely obvious as not a duplicate just from the title, and I couldn't fathom the need to edit it.  I just thought there should be a simple Reopen button or something.  Thanks @BDL

Comment: @Ivar well that is great!! I just wish that was available at a lower reputation.  I've been using this site and actively giving both questions and answers for several years now.  And yet, my reputation is not anywhere near high enough to request a reopen, even though I feel that I'm more than qualified to.  But I guess that's ok, since now I know I need to actively Edit someone else's question if I feel its incorrectly marked as duplicate.  Maybe everything will be smoother sailing now.

Comment: Actually, for that matter, it seems a bit weird that I have the privileges to Edit someone else's question, yet I do NOT have the privileges to cast a vote to reopen.  That is REALLY weird to me.

Comment: @JamesHoux You don't have the [privilege to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) someone's question. Anyone can _suggest_ an edit, that needs to be reviewed by people who have that privilege.

Comment: @JamesHoux: You do not even have to privilege to edit question without having your edit to be reviewed (this comes at 2k). Your edit (if it goes through) may push the question into the reopen review queue. People there can than vote to reopen it.

Comment: @BDL Thank you for the clarification.  I took this for granted, because every Edit I ever made was apparently swiftly approved.  LOL  Well I understand the system better now.  And I'm satisfied with the explanations.  Thank you to all who chimed in on this.