# Is it allowed to mark questions as duplicate by linking to questions which have some small hints to a possible solution in it?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I asked a question which was immediately marked as duplicate and closed.

The "duplicate" is showing a hint on how the problem can possibly solved, but it is not a duplicate at all.

It says I have to edit my question to explain why my question is not a duplicate, I did that but there is still no reaction.

**Question:**

[How to replace chars in text in realtime without loosing cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455092/how-to-replace-chars-in-text-in-realtime-without-loosing-cursor-position)

**"Duplicate":**

[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox)

Comment: Side note: edit on the linked post is not appropriate (which you probably know) - instead of updating question inline with information why it is not duplicate you @ - asking someone "why it is closed"... and "EDIT:" is never appropriate...

Comment: Side note 2: "This is at most a small part of the answer needed to solve my question. Why was my question closed" seem to argue that question should be closed as too broad instead of duplicate... please consider to edit your edit to align with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not-or-what-ca/252254#252254 guidance

Comment: I'd wait more than an hour for a response before complaining that there is no response. An edit puts the question into the reopen queue, which will then be seen by people with sufficient rep to access that queue. Incidentally, the word you're looking for in the title is "losing", not "loosing" :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reopened the question. As you said, it is helpful towards a solution, but it does not really answer the question.

Thousands of questions get asked each day, most of them are duplicates. We review hundreds of them each day per person. Not all decisions are accurate, mistakes do happen. That's what the reopen queue is for. There are currently ~140 questions in the queue, so it takes some time till your question gets reviewed.

The next time, please wait a little till taking it to Meta... the reviewers already handle that.

You can see if it is in the queue and how many people reviewed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58455092/timeline)

Comment: Thank you. I will wait at least a day next time

Comment: It also helps to keep in mind that what may be an obvious connection or leap to an expert isn’t necessarily obvious to the average user. As such, if you keep calm and explain your inability to make the logical leap, rather than getting upset about your question being closed, you can likely persuade the expert to reopen and post an answer that explicitly connects the dots—an answer that will then be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @CodyGray - Or comment to connect the dots. I comment in easily 80% of the questions I close as dupes, even obvious ones. Because...better helpful than not. :-)