# Can I ask for a rebuttal on a question marked as duplicate

Tags: support

My question was marked as a duplicate by Community:
[Efficiently reading only some columns from parquet file on blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130206/efficiently-reading-only-some-columns-from-parquet-file-on-blob-storage/59141231#59141231)

I can understand why, but I think my flavor of the question (and especially the provided and accepted answer) contain specific and **important** information that does not exist in the linked question. Specifically - I asked generally about parquet column scans over cloud storage, but the answer was specific to fastparquet and dask, and this information does not exist in the linked question which talks about Spark.

I do think, however, that I should slightly change the title and remove the request to give answers that apply to Spark from the question body. I can also add the dask and fastparquet tags (and remove the spark tag). That way the question (and already provided answer) become python+dask+fastparquet specific and that's a good thing.

How can I do this?

Comment: Huh? That appears to be closed by community, which means it got closed as a duplicate because you yourself accepted the flag to close it after it got cast. If you thought the question shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate, making that point would've been a lot easier before you closed it as a duplicate yourself.

Comment: How can you do this? You edit the question. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not-or-what-ca

Comment: @ErikA I think you're right, I actually didn't remember that. I thought about this whole thing now because I was actually trying to recall the answer I was given ;) and reading it now I realized closing as dup was wrong (and indeed I was part of the mistake). I'm still interested to hear if there's a way to reverse this

Comment: @beaker thanks. Edited the question and voted to reopen