# Should we handle badly phrased titles using closure or edit?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, editing-help

The question stems from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59914252/1364007).

The question was closed as a duplicate. Although I disagree with the closure, I want to focus here on what me and the closer did agree about: the misleading title.

The question title has succumbed to the XY problem, where it is based on a presumed solution (using flags) rather than the actual problem (processing a list using a trigger).

However, the question body itself did not actually succumb to the XY problem. It does explain the core problem, it contains a description by the poster on exactly what they are trying to achieve, and it showcases an attempt at solving the problem (i.e. the presumed solution of using a flag).
The proposed solution may not be a good one, but it doesn't actually obfuscate the underlying problem - which is generally the source of the issue with XY problems.

In my opinion, the question is therefore valid, though the title does warrant a corrective edit. However, the question was instead closed as a duplicate based on *solely the title*, not the actual question body. (I'm paraphrasing the closer's comment, not just my interpretation).

I'm trying to understand here whether my interpretation of the community standards is incorrect, or whether I am correct in thinking this question should have been edited, not closed.

To generalize my question: How do we respond to a question whose body follows community standards but its title is misleading? (in an easily fixable way, if that matters)

---

As a small addition, as this was raised in the original comment discussion: I do agree that e.g. a "needs focus" closure can be warranted before the question is then edited and reopened.

However, I'm not quite sure the same applies to a "duplicate" closure. If we presume to already know the answer (i.e. the duplicate), then we presume to already know the question, and it makes no sense to then retroactively allow someone to change the question to something completely different that the (once presumed correct) duplicate answer no longer applies to. That would violate the extent to which editing is allowed (i.e. not asking a completely different question), no?

Comment: Can you clarify why standard "edit the question to show it is not duplicate" does not apply to this/similar cases?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'm unsure what you mean, isn't that essentially what I mean when I suggest editing? Though I do mean only editing the _title_, not the question body. Note that, for my linked case, I have actually edited the question and have voted to reopen it (and I just checked, it was reopened) - my question on meta is more about whether the initial closure was actually the correct approach.

Comment: If  your question is "should one vote as duplicate if they believe it is duplicate"... in the past the answer was "yes"... (but who knows what the current guidance is)... (Side note: I do have the same gold badge and I agree with closure - it provided better route for `async` code which likely requires thread safe synchronization, also indeed not as targeted as answer you provided... )

Comment: For the part whether it is it ok to edit question after it is closed as duplicate the  answer is obviously yes because it is the exact guidance on how to re-open question (preferably edit like "tried suggested duplicate {link}, but it is different because...) You may want to [edit] post to clarify why you believe it is not good idea (make sure to refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not-or-what-ca to explain that)

Comment: Edit should always be the first attempt in moderation. If that fails / is impossible, consider your further options: down, close. delete vote.