# Why was this post closed? The comments are not even relevant to the question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Why was this question closed ([x-sendfile - mysql update query breaks it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062713/x-sendfile-mysql-update-query-breaks-it))?  (THE DUP ISN'T A DUP) The comments are not even relevant to the question.  I never indicated that $member_id is an INT.  Nor did I indicate I had any mysql errors...

They indicate there is a similar post ([mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param))?  What's similar exactly?  Because both involve mysql?  My mysql query works fine...  no problems there at all.

I have since posted the complete code.  I flagged it for reopening.  Maybe someone can explain to me what I've done wrong here...

Comment: Why would a question need to be answered to be closed? Closing a question is to prevent answers to it.... If your point is "the dupe isn't a dupe"... then that's different

Comment: Yes, my point is that the dupe isn't a dup...  did I not explain that well enough?

Comment: The code was originally minimal - showing only the relevant part, but people commented "where is your database connection ?"

   After it was closed, I posted the complete code.

Comment: So...where's the error code you get back indicating that your problem is different?  All I see is code and a protest about how it's not a dupe; adding your exact error message would remove more doubt.

Comment: The database connection code was added after it was closed...

Comment: There is no error code... nothing is logged to php... nothing appears in the browser... the playback just dies.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not-or-what-ca

Comment: Looks like it has been reopened at this point.

Answer (score 5):

With the information you gave us the duplicate seems to be correct. If you have applied the suggestions from the target post's answer and you still have the same problem, then you need to update the question, **showing us how you applied the suggestions** and clearly stating it did not help you. Then the post **might be** reopened.

I agree with RiggsFolly here and his judgement. There's no reason to be mad at him. However, you have not shown enough information to help us help you. We are willing to help and the comments are meant to be for us asking clarifications, so that together we can come to a solution.

If you have updated the question with more details, then the question will go through the queue and be reopened, but it looks like you have drawn enough attention already for it to happen.

Comment: I'm not mad at RiggsFolly at all...  Just wanted the post back on there so I can find a solution to my problem.  It looks like the question was reinstated...

   It's a very weird issue...  I'm going to talk with my hosting providers - may even have to pay them for help with it.  I'll let you guys know what I find out...

Comment: I updated the post...  Do you think it needs further updating yet?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry yeah, I'm nrsbus

Comment: Your question has much more details. The problem is that from our side we can still only guess or suggest more ways to help you debug. In the end you need to try different things and find the error in your code. Have you tried removing all non-critical code to see if the issue can be reproduced with minimal code? Have you tried executing the request without JS? Use postman if you can't otherwise. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Working on all that now...   BTW, man, it's tough to get cred in this place...  I'm down to 17 just because of that last post.  Tough place!  Well, I'm learning I guess...  Nobody started at the top...  Even a preschool kid like myself has to plow forward... Maybe one day my cred will break 20 again.