# Closed Question Seems to Have Nuance That Differs from Offered Duplicates

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

The following question was closed and marked as a duplicate: [Position containers with cut of corners next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326543/position-containers-with-cut-of-corners-next-to-each-other)

I was working on a solution with a code-snippet to find the question closed before I could submit the answer. The meta question below only deals with the process for the OP whose question is closed: ["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not - or - What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not-or-what-ca)

I'm asking as a community member wishing to provide a solution and who has looked at the proposed duplicates and feel they aren't adequate.

The proposed duplicates all deal with skewed layouts at it pertains to either images or a situation where the inner content was not affected by the skewed borders.

The nuance with this question, and why I think it should remain open, is that the question has to do with clipping content within the skewed containers based on the skew itself. It's one thing to manipulate an image with CSS, borders, backgrounds, etc, and entirely another to manipulate inner content, which could be text or anything else.

In other words, the solutions offered in the duplicate examples would not get the OP to a solution clearly from the accepted answers. Certain principles from each of the proposed duplicates might be helpful but none would be self-evident answers to the question being posed.

The question itself might require more clarity from the OP, such as they provided in the comments on the original post, but it probably shouldn't be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @user4642212 only partially. The question you reference only deals with the OP and how they should respond. As someone who took the time to craft an answer and was blocked by the question being closed, what is the process for me?

Comment: 3k-users can vote to reopen the question. Any _edit_ would place it in the Reopen Review Queue, so you could either suggest editing the SO question or edit it yourself to try and explain why the duplicate target doesn’t fit.

Comment: ok I wll add more duplicate target if you want .. there is a lot of them, give me few minutes

Comment: added two others, I cannot add more but I still know a lot more

Comment: @TemaniAfif None of the proposals answer the question, even the two new ones you added. The answer must involve a skewed div, but there is more to be done to handle the content of the second div being clipped (a feature they want).

Answer (score 3):

I closed the question as duplicate with many duplicates target that gives all the possible ideas that allow the OP to achieve what he wants. A duplicate is never meant to give a *ready-to-copy* code but here is an answer from one duplicate that he can use without a lot of changes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56812750/8620333

To obtain what he want with a clipped content:

```css
.apartments-showCase-content {
  width: calc(70% + 40px);
  background:green;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,calc(100% - 80px) 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  
  margin-right:-80px; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  z-index:1;
}

.apartments-showCase-image {
  width: calc(30% + 40px);
  background: #222;
  background: red;
}
.apartments-section {
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<section class="apartments-section">
  <div class="apartments-showCase-content"> hello I am content</div>
  <div class="apartments-showCase-image">hello I am content</div>
</section>
```

Many other answers can be edited to achieve the same but I let the OP do some effort for that.

Comment: This is not even the accepted answer on the question. Would the OP even get to this?

Comment: Just imagine instead of closing the question you gave this answer or a modified version. Then at least it would have been an accepted answer.

Comment: Duplicates are not dependant only on the accepted answer.

Comment: @wlh It doesn't matter if it's acccept or not, it's one answer among all the others and it's up to the OP (or anyone) to do the effort to check all the answers and try as much as possible. As I said, the purpose it not to give a ready-to-copy-past code. You can clearly see that the code I made isn't far from the one I picked for that answer which confirm the duplicate. This was a simple example and I can do the same with many other answers.

Comment: @DavisBroda I agree, it has to do with the questions. I'm trying to argue that the questions are exactly duplicates.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree. I'm not certain they find that question unless they are searching for `skew`, which from the question itself, seems they may not have known yet.

Comment: We do in fact have a way to help OPs find their answer, when they do not know the domain vocabulary. We mark it as a duplicate of the cannonical question, and that gives them a pointer to where they can find the answer (and maybe teaches them some new vocabulary as a bonus). If the vocabulary is different enough that the duplicate is a good signpost, then will generally stick around and continue to help other people who lack vocabulary find their answers. A well written signpost duplicate is not a bad thing.

Comment: @whl just as reminder - "accepted" does not mean "correct", "useful", "answering the question"  or anything like that. It only means "helped OP the most". There are cases where accepted answer suggest the worst possible option but OP likes it...