# Undo flagging own question as duplicated

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

Stack Overflow prompted me with a question on one of my posts, asking if someone who commented linked something that helped me. It also said it was for my own records only. So I clicked yes, because the linked post linked me to more documentation that ultimately solved my problem. But as soon as I clicked that, it said thank you for flagging your problem as a duplicate of [the other question...]. My question is certainly not a duplicate of this, just linked to the appropriate docs. I looked all over and couldn't find any undo button.

I would like to no longer have this flagged as a duplicate since I never told it to to begin with, and so that if someone is searching for a similar problem they don't find my post but then immediately leave to visit the not so "duplicate". Thanks!

Comment: If you feel that your answer is better than those in the duplicate, then one option is to post your answer as an answer to the alleged duplicate

Comment: It's not better, just for an entirely different issue. I didn't know that clicking the "this helped me" button would mark it as a duplicate. The only thing about it that helped was that it has a link to the right page of the software's documentation in it.

Comment: It really does not matter how exactly post closed as duplicate - the way to re-open it is always the same - edit and vote to re-open (if you can). Since first edit after closure will put post in re-open queue for review make sure your edit actually makes it clear how duplicate does not solve your problem (beware  that variations of "not a f**ing duplicate" is not enough, edit needs to explain why)

Comment: Perhaps adding some clarification to the "was this helpful" prompt that it will close the question as a duplicate? It is easy enough for another question to be helpful in some way but not provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit unclear on exactly what was going through your mind at the time you read the message and/or what the problem is now.

The definition of "duplicate" on Stack Overflow is "these two questions have the same answer". If the answer in both cases was (as it seems to be to me, with the caveat that I am not a subject matter expert) to "use the lookup helper", per [the documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup), then the two questions would be duplicates.

This is why the prompt is asking you, "Does this answer your question?" If it does, then that proves that your question has the same answer as the other suggested question, and thus, it is a duplicate.

The reason we close questions as duplicates is because they have the same answers, so it's best for everyone (both you, the original asker, and others who may come along later looking for an answer) to consolidate the information in one place. That not only makes it easier to find, but also easier to keep up to date. Having a question closed as a duplicate doesn't necessarily mean that you did anything wrong. *Sometimes* duplicates are obvious, and you could (should) have avoided asking them by doing a bit of research first. Other times, it is only obvious to an expert who already knows the answer that the question is a duplicate.

At any rate, there is no "undo" button for this, and I really don't think there should be. It is far too open to misuse. For whatever reason, a large number of users have a strongly negative reaction to their question being marked as a duplicate—even when it clearly is.

There is a way to undo a duplicate closure, though, and that is for [the same users who have privileges to close questions as duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to re-open the question. You can get the process of re-opening started by editing your question to clarify why it is not a duplicate (meaning, why the two questions do not have the same answer).

See also: ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i)