# Moderators deleting my comments for no reason!

Tags: support, comments, moderation

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301624/how-can-i-add-tf-keras-layers-additiveattention-in-my-model?noredirect=1#comment113890692_64301624) was my question of Stack Overflow. As soon as I started the question, I commented:

> If you are downvoting my question then please tell the reason in comments, so that I can do my best to improve it!

After commenting this, it got deleted in a day or two. But, I didn't mind it as it didn't stop my learning. Then, someone named 'Amit Sharma' commented:

> possible explanation and solution in stackoverflow.com/a/62949137/6827830

And then, I wanted to ask something about that link provided by Amit Sharma so I commented my question.

This was my question asked to Amit Sharma about the link he provided:

> @AmitSharma Thank you for your reply, but the answer in the link, was that an implementation of Bahdanau Attention? Because, in that post, nowhere is written that it was a Bahdanau attention implementation.

And a moderator deleted this comment!

Then, Amit Sharma commented:

> If the provided link to the answer solved your problem, please let this be known in this thread for others encountering the same issue

But, I already said, and a moderator deleted it.

Not only this. If you also see the first comment by datamansahil, he asked this:

> Does this help? - tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/…

I even replied to him in the comments and even that got deleted!

This is too frustrating, because first of all, I placed a bounty on it and so am losing my 50 reputation, and moderators don't let me comment, and reply to other users.

I lost my 50 reputation for nothing. And 50 reputation means a lot to me!

Comment: If you get a reasoning why your comments were deleted in form of a private moderator message, it's mostly that you've violated some rules and either being warned about continuing such behavior, or that a suspension has been applied. So just be happy this didn't happen, and consider that your comments were received as being unconstructive noise. Comments are (and ever were) 2nd class citizens of SO posts, and prone to be tidied at any time. Just move on.

Comment: Side note: linked question is in suboptimal shape right now - since you asked for a lot of attention via meta *and* bounty you'd better show your research and narrow things down... So far it reads "I looked for tutorial *I like* but can't find one, so write on for me, required to match my taste"... In general asking for whole detailed tutorial is already too broad, essentially asking for one *you will find good* (without any criteria how to decide whether it is good or not) is not helping your case. "I tried a lot to find good tutorials" in not showing your research of the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I haven't wrote a thing what you are telling that I wrote. Please read the post carefully. I have just asked, 'how can i put that layer in my model'. I never asked for the whole tutorial. Please read the post carefully!

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like most of these comments should really result in edits to your question. e.g.

- I'm looking for an answer that uses (or maybe doesn't use) Bahdanau Attention, because...
- Or [this answer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/AdditiveAttention) does not answer my question because...

Once you've edited your question you can flag their comments as no longer needed. A whole pile of comments that needs to be waded through in addition to the question itself is less than optimal and you want to make your question as attractive as posssible to anyone who might answer it.

You can add a comment to say you've edited the question but the main thing is to get all the pertinent information in that place. Though in your case even that is probably unnecessary given the bounty will attract people anyway.

And of course don't ask just about voting, it's not really constructive. If someone wanted to comment, they would have done so.

Comment: note that edits to the question should preferably not be added to the end with a note like "edit:", but instead be incorporated into the existing question, otherwise they are not much better than comments.

Comment: @RobertLongson But, what about the comment in which I asked the commentor a question about his comment. Why did that got deleted?

Comment: Because either the comment answered your question in which case it does not need a response, or it didn't help in which case you edit your question to explain why. I feel Cody and I have said this a number of times now. I'd edit my answer if I knew why you're not getting the point. And then I'd flag all your comments... See where this is going?

Comment: @NitinAgarwal - You are providing clarification to your question by commenting instead of editing your question.  I always flagged unnecessary commentary like that, I refuse to explain each flag, since it’s already explicitly explained in the help center

Answer (score 18):

Comments discussing votes (whether upvotes or downvotes) are inappropriate. These *will* be deleted by moderators. Do not leave any more comments like this one:

> If you are downvoting my question then please tell the reason in comments, so that I can do my best to improve it!

If someone wants to leave a comment with an explanation, they will. If not, they don't have to. In the *best* case, comments like this are just noise; in the worst case, they can be perceived as bullying downvoters. For more background information, see: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Regarding the rest of your comments, it seems like you misunderstand the purpose of Stack Overflow and are trying to treat it like a discussion forum or a chat server. Comments are intended to suggest possible improvements to a post. They're not intended for two-way discussion between users. Amit Sharma's comment was suggesting something he thought was related and might help you. If it doesn't, then that's fine, but no reply is necessary. If you want to clarify that your question is not a duplicate (e.g., to avoid future users from voting to close it as a duplicate of the one Amit linked), then [you should edit your question to emphasize the differences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i).

Note that having comments deleted doesn't cause you to lose any reputation. None of this has anything to do with the bounty you set on that question. Bounties are meant to attract *answers*, not discussion in comments.

As a final note—when a comment is deleted by a moderator, it's best not to just keep re-posting the same comment. It was probably deleted for a reason, and continuing to just re-post the same comment is an abuse of the system. The only recourse that moderators have at that point is to either suspend your account's privileges or lock commenting altogether on that particular question. Neither of those are particularly attractive options, but we will use them if you just don't seem to be getting the hint and keep posting a comment we've repeatedly deleted.

Comment: But I wanted to ask Amit Sharma a question about his comment. Why did that got deleted?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum or a chat server. There was no reason to ask any questions or have any type of discussion.

Comment: @NITINAGARWAL Cody explicitly references this and explains why in his answer. I don't get why you think that's unclear but if you explain why you can't understand his answer I'm sure he'll edit it and then with no use of irony whatsoever, delete all these comments.

Comment: You quote the passage but then when it doesn't say what you want it to say, you add a reason that's not mentioned there. You don't see why that might not work for you as a justification?

Comment: I'm humbled by your confidence in me, but no promises on that last condition, @Robert. I can't remember the last time I did *anything* without a healthy sense of irony. :-)