# Why did my question about CSS flexbox get closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

A few days ago, my [simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500455/how-do-i-keep-my-flex-layout-and-make-sure-all-the-flex-items-are-the-same-size) about CSS Flexbox got closed because it was "a duplicate" of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/targeting-flex-items-on-the-last-or-specific-row). Now that I am thinking about it, the answers to these questions could be slightly similar at some level, but my question is completely different.

I tried to edit the post by stating what makes it different, but the edit never showed and it is still closed. I also raised a flag that got declined.

I edited my original question again, and now it isn't a duplicate of the other post.

Can its closure be re-evaluated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i)

Comment: The question doesn't show any edits, pending or otherwise.  What happened when you tried to edit it?

Comment: If you think your question isn't a duplicate follow the instructions. Edit it to explain *why* it isn't one. And no "This isn't a duplicate" isn't an explanation. You can then ping the user that closed it in the comments, if you want, to let them know you've update the question to further elaborate your problem.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like your question was closed within 2 minutes of your posting it. Did you edit the question within a few minutes after that? If so, the system probably didn't treat that as an edit (because it was in the 5 minute grace period), and so your question wasn't sent to the reopen review queue.

Comment: "*Now that I am thinking about it, the answers to these questions could be slightly similar at some level, but my question is completely different.*" what matters is whether or not the duplicate target contains answers that help you. Does it, or does it not? "*The reason I am making this post is because I am being punished for having my question closed.*" it takes a lot more than a single closure to get a question ban or even approach it. See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: I edited the original question again so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @cigien Yes, I think it was around a few minutes after I posted the question.

Comment: I've edited out the rambling about the post-ban. You either want to have your question opened or you "complain" about the quality measures this site has in place, but it can't be both. I have picked the option to have this meta post about the re-opening of your question as that has the best chance of succeeding while the other option is likely to not be received very well / have great success for your case.

Comment: Heads up that a question being a duplicate doesn't contribute to the question ban. Questions being badly received does, even when the question is deleted. You might want to focus on fixing up any old questions if you are close to a question ban. You can also ask moderators to dig up your deleted posts if you do not know them anymore.

Comment: @rene Thanks, but because this post has at least 5 downvotes, does this mean that I don't have a good case?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't have any more deleted questions anymore because I undeleted my only one that was deleted. Now, the bad posts I have are -2 and -1.

Comment: @Shivam these type of questions hardly ever go well, specially if you combine them with post ban whining and calling your question "good". It would be much more productive if these posts approached meta a tad more humble. You could for example have assumed that there were improvements possible for your question and ask us about that. It is too late now. Let's hope the next visitors are a bit more willing to look for the long lasting value in this meta question.

Comment: I looked at the question and I would have closed it as the same duplicate and I trust the opinion of the gold badge closer,

Comment: You have the following 3 deleted questions: [Q1](//stackoverflow.com/q/66726762), [Q2](//stackoverflow.com/q/65451501), and [Q3](//stackoverflow.com/q/64037385); and 10 deleted answers: [A1](//stackoverflow.com/a/68218337), [A2](//stackoverflow.com/a/67994113), [A3](//stackoverflow.com/a/67993722), [A4](//stackoverflow.com/a/67992684), [A5](//stackoverflow.com/a/67944398), [A6](//stackoverflow.com/a/67944317), [A7](//stackoverflow.com/a/67929338), [A8](//stackoverflow.com/a/67928952), [A9](//stackoverflow.com/a/67844434), and [A10](//stackoverflow.com/a/67807896).

Comment: @Makyen Sorry, I didn't remember those from a long time ago. Some of those I deleted because there were no comments/answers, and at the time I wasn't aware of how it could get me post-banned. If I undelete some of them and improve them, would it help me get out of risk of being post-banned?

Comment: Also, [A2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67994113), [A3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67993722), [A4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67992684), and [A10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67807896) are deleted because the post author deleted it. Am I being punished for these as well?

Comment: @Shivam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993712/is-it-worth-to-learn-ejs-or-other-related-libraries-in-2021/67993722#67993722 was not deleted by the owner, but by community moderation. You already knew that the question is likely to be deleted if you felt it necessary to start your answer with "This question shouldn't really be on StackOverflow..."

Answer (score 10):

> Can its closure be re-evaluated?

It's still a perfect duplicate for me.

> I edited my original question again, and now it isn't a duplicate of the other post.

I don't see any relevant edits that make your question different. You don't need JS at all. The duplicate gives a full list of CSS method to fix your issue.

A hint: you don't need flexbox here but CSS grid.

Another hint: even if you still need flexbox, take the time to read the 15 questions listed within Micheal_B answers where he said

> In case Grid is not an option, here's a list of similar questions containing various flexbox hacks:

---

Sorry to say it but I don't think you took the time to read the duplicate because if you did it won't take you more than 20min to find the answer.