# This PHP question was closed as a dupe of a very general question, and should be reopened

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I request to reopen it. My question is not similar to the question it was closed as a duplicate of. There is no error message and telling a person how to show them does not provide even reasonable insight.

There is an answer available in the comments under the question

*[Why does this function not populate the second digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056444)*

The duplicate banner links to a question about how to show error messages in PHP, but the question is not about error messages, *apart from some superfluous messages unrelated to the error shown in the comments there are no relevant errors.*

The actual solution is related to the operation of the `empty()` command with [some demonstration PHP here](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/ijzhc?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=).

Comment: If you want to post an answer, do so on the duplicate target.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i)

Comment: Yikes, that question's been in reopen review for 21 days without receiving any votes (in either direction)...that's not great. :-\

Comment: Regarding **this** question: some more detail about why it's not a duplicate would be nice, without forcing people to read multiple pages of question+comments.

Comment: @Larnu The duplicate is not similar. My question says, "my question is not similar to the question it was closed as a duplicate of."

Comment: Simply saying something isn't something doesn't make it not that thing, @Willtech . Saying "this isn't a dupe" with no explanation isn't going to get a question closed as a dupe reopened.

Comment: From our perspective, how does *'My question says, "my question is not similar to the question it was closed as a duplicate of."'* show to us how/why the question is not a duplicate? How informative do you imagine your statement to really be?

Answer (score 9):

While those "catch-all" dupe targets are not great, the question is not worth reopening.

It's a bit of a mess, and I think it would be impossible to salvage something useful for future visitors from there.

If via extended comment discussion you were able to find a solution, **great.** But for the next time, please try harder to isolate the issue you are having.

The problems demonstrated on the question are about extremely basic language concepts, and by carefully debugging (not mentioning checking the docs) would allow you to at least fix the code to a "it works" state, even if not pretty.

Also, in the question you say that your "refactored" code shown there  produces the same output than your first attempt; and yet it's impossible that it does. And easily proved that it doesn't.

Again, by working in reducing/isolating the problems to a minimal example this kind of thing wouldn't happen. The question code has too many problems, contradictions and moving parts to be that.

I believe the question would have been better closed as either "needs focus" / "needs details/clarity" / "needs debugging details", but I imagine the gold badger closed it as a "broad" dupe both for expediency and to direct you likely useful resources to deal with the question issue(s).

In any case, it's not worth reopening just to close it for a different reason, and I've added a more specific dupe target that deals directly with one of the issues exhibited by the question's code.

Comment: I mean... damn. 44 answers. That's no longer a duplicate target, that's a book.

Comment: Yeah, those "canonicals" tend to be pretty useless, truth be told. It's not much better than posting RTFM comments, IMO. (Although I'm pretty sure I have closed against some of them more than once out of frustration with some questions).

Comment: @Gimby You should see the one for undefined references in C++-land. Anything an asker could credibly ask is answered in that monster, but good luck to Joe Newb actually finding it or recognizing that they found it.

Comment: @user4581301 no easier than finding a question other than that one that would help such a user

Comment: Sure, you possibly realise the conversation was the reason for finding the solution, it was a necessary part of working out the answer, but it could also have been existing knowledge to someone if anybody actually bothered to take a serious interest. This demonstrates the answer you just need to click run for the output. https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/ijzhc?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, that's a terrible target. I don't use that one at all, unless the question is literally "what is an undefined reference?". If it's about a particular kind of undefined reference I try to find a target that addresses that specific aspect.

Comment: @cigien Similar. If I can't I'll plug my nose, use it, and leave a comment saying which answer they need to read.

Comment: @user4581301  I would not mind an indexed monster with ToC if it answered the question. The rudeness to pass off to 'how to show error messages' reverts to childism.