# How can I post a question that doesn't cross the text limit but has an image that explains things better?

Tags: support, asking-questions, images, character-limit

In the following question, and I made an effort to explain what I desired with a paragraph of text in addition to an image to illustrate the problem, but Stack Overflow asks me for more text.

I have nothing else to add since the image explained it all. I later added a second paragraph for the system to allow me to post the question.

[HTML/CSS What is the best way to center navigation when also would like a logo on one side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554810/html-css-what-is-the-best-way-to-center-navigation-when-also-would-like-a-logo-o)

Does Stack Overflow only expect text? Images are sometimes much more useful.

How can I post questions where an image is sufficient to properly explain the desired result?

Comment: Did you originally include the first paragraph when the system didn't allow you to post the question or did you try to post the question with no text at all?

Comment: Yes. ---> ...and this comment wants 11 more characters...

Comment: The first. <--and it still wants 4 more characters....

Comment: I didn't personally downvote your question but if I had to guess, it's probably because it sounds like a rant, as opposed to someone genuinely trying to understand how the system works. That said, I agree that many users on Meta are too quick to press the downvote button (in their defense, we get so much crap on Meta). I prefer to give new users the benefit of the doubt unless the quality of the post and/or the user's attitude is pretty bad. In any case, please note that up/down votes on meta don't affect the reputation, so don't worry too much about it and try not to take it personally.

Comment: @SabitostandswithUkraine No, in this case they posted their code as text along with an image of what they want.

Comment: Can we please stop shooting people down by downvoting their meta questions to oblivion and closing them as duplicates of barely related posts? The question isn't really that bad. I've edited it to improve the wording and add more details from the comments. Hopefully, it lands better now.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine This meta question shows no research effort. It is an easily found common duplicate, so not helpful. "SO asked for more writing" is unclear--the circumstances about which they are asking.

Comment: @philipxy:  The meta question is *fine*.  In the context of the OP's question, they're asking about a narrow, specific question in which their question uses images and they seem to be getting downvoted for that reason.  In those cases it's a lot simpler to offer more pointed/guided advice to someone than it is to close their question as the generic dupe.  That is to say, while the answer in the dupe would be *similar* to the one I provided, the one provided here is more to the point of the OP's specific concern.

Comment: The functionality should check if there is an image. If there is it should check to see if it has a description. If not, it should ask the user to add a description of the picture. That would both satisfy @makoto's 2nd bullet, which is the one that matter here. That way, images for questions that are visual are easier to ask.

Comment: There's no way for the system to be able to tell whether the image description or even the image itself is useful. I've seen a lot of alt text that just says things like "screenshot" or "error message" instead of actually describing the image. Sometimes the image isn't helpful because it doesn't show something we needed to see or it actually isn't clear what we're supposed to get from looking at it.

Comment: The [FAQ for Duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252254/4076315) says that you should explain why the dupe target doesn't answer your question so I rolled back the edit removing your explanation. That said, I don't think the 2nd paragraph of that explanation helps. It doesn't really matter whether the dupe target uses an image, it only matters whether it answes the question. Your explanation for why it doesn't solve the issue should be enough.

Comment: @BSMP Can put a min word limit on alt text too. People can write a bad problem statement at the word limit. So people not providing good alt text is not a reason not to give images more weight. The whole content of the question should determine the quality of the question - if an image makes it easier, and faster to understand then the question is better quality.

Comment: Well the alt text already counts towards the minimum word count for a post, right? There isn’t a reason to alter that minimum just because an image exists.

Comment: If alt text does contribute than the instructions should indicate that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The guidance is to use images *sparingly*.  As in, only when you know you can't avoid them.

The reasons are straightforward:

- If someone puts their code in a picture (which is almost always what happens), someone else can't just copy their code and paste it into their environment to run and observe independently.
- If someone is otherwise using an image without any text to explain or support it, it means that those who use screen readers are limited in their ability to partake in the answering of it.

For your case, because you're describing what your *desired* outcome is and what you've attempted to do to get there, I don't think there's a real issue with the image being there.  It is at least in support of your goal, and sometimes UI questions tend to be visual-heavy.

...As to whether or not it's a dupe?  You'd have to ask someone with a CSS badge.  I only have battle scars which aren't good enough as far as the dupe system is concerned.